# How do you stretch an image to fill a <div> while keeping the image's aspect-ratio?

Tags: image, html, size

I need to make this image stretch to the maximum size possible without overflowing it's `<div>` or skewing the image.

I can't predict the aspect-ratio of the image, so there's no way to know whether to use:

```
<img src="url" style="width: 100%;">
```

or

```
<img src="url" style="height: 100%;">
```

I can't use both (i.e. style="width: 100%; height: 100%;") because that will stretch the image to fit the `<div>`.

The `<div>` has a size set by percentage of the screen, which is also unpredictable.

Comment: If you need the image to fill either height or width to the corresponding dimensions of the div, I can only think of using javascript. Is that something you are keen to explore?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787839/resize-image-proportionally-with-css

Comment: The answer is [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit), see (and upvote) @daniels [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30242945)

Comment: @aexl Thanks for alerting me to this. This question is 11.5 years old and I accepted that answer the same day. XD I selected a different answer, that seems to be more relevant than the one you mentioned. Let me know if you disagree. I'm actually not a web developer, just C++, so I wouldn't know much about choosing the best answer here.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

If you're able to set the image as a `background-image` then you can do something like this, which will crop the image without stretching it:

```
<div style="background-image: url(...); background-size: cover; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
```

If you need to stick with an `<img>` tag, then as of 2019, you can now use the `object-fit` css property that accepts the following values:
`fill | contain | cover | none | scale-down`

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

As an example, you could have a container that holds an image:

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="" class="container_img" />
</div>

.container {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50%;
}

.container_img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 207):

Update 2016:

Modern browser behave much better. All you should need to do is to set the image width to 100% ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/pu2p1u9g/))

```
.container img {
   width: 100%;
}
```

---

Since you don't know the aspect ratio, you'll have to use some scripting. Here is how I would do it with jQuery ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/RNVaZ/)):

CSS

```
.container {
    width: 40%;
    height: 40%;
    background: #444;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.container img.wide {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.container img.tall {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
}​
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
 <img src="http://i48.tinypic.com/wrltuc.jpg" />
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div class="container">
 <img src="http://i47.tinypic.com/i1bek8.jpg" />
</div>
```

Script

```
$(window).load(function(){
 $('.container').find('img').each(function(){
  var imgClass = (this.width/this.height > 1) ? 'wide' : 'tall';
  $(this).addClass(imgClass);
 })
})
```

Comment: Can the user see the image before the resize? Anyone tested this?

Comment: The solution is almost right, you just have to invert the height and width in the css : if the  image is 'tall', then the width should be 100% not the height (wich will be bigger and overflowing). The other way around for the wide photos.

Comment: @mbritto: You're right, I had to change the css to max-width/height and I added a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/RNVaZ/)

Comment: @Mottie is there a way to fit a image of size 930 px width to a container of 960 px without losing the image quality

Comment: @VivekDragon Image quality will always suffer when stretching. The best thing to do is to just have the image at the size you want it.

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer. The question is about images being too small for their container. i.e. how can an image be scaled up to fill its container's width or height, without fudging up the image's aspect ratio. Also, in your demo, removing the `width:auto` or `height:auto` properties does not affect the display of your images. As a matter of fact, of all the properties you're applying to the image, only `max-width: 100%` has any effect at all, and it only effects the landscape image. But most importantly, your answer does not help stretch a small image to fill a larger container.

Comment: Useless code, demo shows nothing at all. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_height.asp Default value for Height and Width is 'auto'. How your 'height: auto;' and 'width: auto;' should influence the element? Other styles for 2 classes are the same. Any idea why this answer got 77 upvotes?

Comment: @BeRocket Yes, the default value is `auto`, you're forcing the image to adjust its size automatically, but limit it in one direction. Also consider that it was answered in 2009... Did you try resizing the result pane in the demo?

Comment: @Mottie `but limit it in one direction` - how? Both `height` and `weight` is set to `auto` by default. You set manually `height` to `auto`. What changed? 'was answered in 2009' - understand but answer is still on high positions in the search results so making it up-to-date would be awesome from your side =)

Comment: @BeRocket I've updated my answer. Interestingly enough, it seems you only need to set the width.

Comment: How about you try `background-size: auto 100%;` (source:http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

Comment: Shouldn't you also have a $(this).removeClass(<the other class in case it's already there?>)?

Comment: No @Chiwda, the class names are only added on window load.

Comment: why this needs jQuery for a simple img in a div? Maybe there is more of a simple way

Answer (score 103):

There is a much easier way to do this using only `CSS` and `HTML`:

**HTML:**

```
<div 
    class="fill" 
    style="background-image: url('path/to/image.jpg');">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.fill {
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

This will place your image as the background, and stretch it to fit the `div` size without distortion.

Comment: is this possible with an undefined number of images ?

Comment: `background-size: cover;` is the real magic here, and it's CSS3 but has reasonable browser support on most recent versions (see: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp )

Comment: It might be worth including the image url in the HTML, in order to separate style and contents, i.e. `<div style="background-image: url('path/to/image.jpg');" class="fill"></div>`

Comment: `background-size: cover` **does not** maintain the aspect ratio, parts of the image that are not proportional to the element are cropped. Refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

Comment: @Alex_Zhong, you misunderstand aspect ratio.  Aspect ratio means that the image is not stretched in any direction (so a perfect circle would not become an oval in either width or height).  Cropping may be a necessary part of maintaining aspect ratio (as it is in the OP's use case).

Comment: It works for Django too.

Answer (score 74):

Not a perfect solution, but this CSS might help.  The zoom is what makes this code work, and the factor should theoretically be infinite to work ideally for small images - but 2, 4, or 8 works fine in most cases.

```css
#myImage {
    zoom: 2;  //increase if you have very small images

    display: block;
    margin: auto;

    height: auto;
    max-height: 100%;

    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I wish this worked in Firefox. Why no `zoom` love from Firefox!?

Comment: Firefox still doesn't have `zoom` implemented, but here is the bug link for future reference: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=390936

Comment: I love this, I save it as .stretchy and make great use of it.

Answer (score 38):

If you can, use background images and set `background-size: cover`. This will make the background cover the whole element.

CSS

```
div {
  background-image: url(path/to/your/image.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

If you're stuck with using inline images there are a few options. First, there is

**object-fit**

This property acts on images, videos and other objects similar to `background-size: cover`.

CSS

```
img {
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Sadly, [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit) is not that great with IE up to version 11 not supporting it at all. The next option uses jQuery

**CSS + jQuery**

HTML

```
<div>
  <img src="image.png" class="cover-image">
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
  height: 8em;
  width: 15em;
}
```

Custom [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/bruvers/cover-image)

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.coverImage = function(contain) {
    this.each(function() {
      var $this = $(this),
        src = $this.get(0).src,
        $wrapper = $this.parent();

      if (contain) {
        $wrapper.css({
          'background': 'url(' + src + ') 50% 50%/contain no-repeat'
        });
      } else {
        $wrapper.css({
          'background': 'url(' + src + ') 50% 50%/cover no-repeat'
        });
      }

      $this.remove();
    });

    return this;
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Use the plugin like this

```
jQuery('.cover-image').coverImage();
```

It will take an image, set it as a background image on the image's wrapper element and remove the `img` tag from the document. Lastly you could use

**Pure CSS**

You might use this as a fallback. The image will scale up to cover it's container but it won't scale down.

CSS

```
div {
  height: 8em;
  width: 15em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div img {
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: none;
  max-height: none;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Hope this might help somebody, happy coding!

Comment: I was looking for a pure CSS solution to have **images fill a given container** without using background-image & background-size and the CSS code here works great for >=IE9 and modern browsers.
[CodePen demo here](http://codepen.io/floq-design/full/EPjKPd/)

Comment: In *Pure CSS*, I removed `min-` and change to `width: 100%; height: 100%;` and work! awesome solution! +1 Thanks!

Comment: `background-size: contain` is also useful if you want none of the image to ever be clipped.

Comment: You can add `zoom:0.001` to the Pure CSS solution to scale down.

Answer (score 20):

Thanks to CSS3

```
img
{
   object-fit: contain;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

IE and EDGE as always outsiders:
http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit

Answer (score 7):

That's impossible with just HTML and CSS, or at least wildly exotic and complicated. If you're willing to throw some javascript in, here's a solution using jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        var $i = $('img#image_to_resize');
        var $c = $img.parent();
        var i_ar = $i.width() / $i.height(), c_ar = $c.width() / $c.height();            
        $i.width(i_ar > c_ar ? $c.width() : $c.height() * (i_ar));
    });
    $(window).resize();
});
```

That will resize the image so that it will always fit inside the parent element, regardless of it's size. And as it's binded to the `$(window).resize()` event, when user resizes the window, the image will adjust.

This does not try to center the image in the container, that would be possible but I guess that's not what you're after.

Comment: I assume $img.parent(); should really be $i.parent();

Comment: today is possible.
{
width: auto;
max-width: none;
max-height: 100%;
object-fit: contain;
}

Answer (score 6):

You can use `object-fit: cover;` on the parent div.

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/

Comment: No IE or Edge support on this yet unfortunately :( http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit

Comment: width: auto;
max-width: none;
max-height: 100%;
object-fit: contain;

Answer (score 5):

Set width and height of the outer `container` div. Then use below styling on img:

```
.container img{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    max-height:100%;
}
```

This will help you to keep an aspect ratio of your img

Comment: it wont fill the div.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to set a max width or height (so that it will not be very large) while keeping the images aspect-ratio, you can do this:

```
img{
   object-fit: contain;
   max-height: 70px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I came across this question searching for a simular problem. I'm making a webpage with responsive design and the width of elements placed on the page is set to a percent of the screen width. The height is set with a vw value.

Since I'm adding posts with PHP and a database backend, pure CSS was out of the question. I did however find the jQuery/javascript solution a bit troblesome, so I came up with a neat (so I think myself at least) solution.

HTML (or php)

```css
div.imgfill {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50%  50%;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 33.333%;
  height: 18vw;
  border: 1px solid black; /*frame of the image*/
  margin: -1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgfill" style="background-image:url(source/image.jpg);">
  This might be some info
</div>
<div class="imgfill" style="background-image:url(source/image2.jpg);">
  This might be some info
</div>
<div class="imgfill" style="background-image:url(source/image3.jpg);">
  This might be some info
</div>
```

By using style="" it's posible to have PHP update my page dynamically and the CSS-styling together with style="" will end up in a perfectly covered image, scaled to cover the dynamic div-tag.

Answer (score 4):

To make this image stretch to the **maximum size possible without overflowing** it's  or skewing the image.

Apply...

```
img {
  object-fit: cover;
  height: -webkit-fill-available;
}
```

styles to the image.

Answer (score 3):

Using this method you can fill in your div with the image varying ratio of divs and images.

**jQuery:**

```
$(window).load(function(){
   $('body').find(.fillme).each(function(){
      var fillmeval = $(this).width()/$(this).height();
      var imgval = $this.children('img').width()/$this.children('img').height();
      var imgClass;
      if(imgval > fillmeval){
          imgClass = "stretchy";
      }else{
          imgClass = "stretchx";
      }
      $(this).children('img').addClass(imgClass);
   });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="fillme">
   <img src="../images/myimg.jpg" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.fillme{
  overflow:hidden;
}
.fillme img.stretchx{
  height:auto;
  width:100%;
}
.fillme img.stretchy{
  height:100%;
  width:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This did the trick for me

```css
div img {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 500px;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you working with IMG tag, it's easy.

I made this:

```
<style>
        #pic{
            height: 400px;
            width: 400px;
        }
        #pic img{
            height: 225px;               
            position: relative;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
</style>

<div id="pic"><img src="images/menu.png"></div>

$(document).ready(function(){
            $('#pic img').attr({ 'style':'height:25%; display:none; left:100px; top:100px;' })
)}
```

but i didn't find how to make it work with #pic { background:url(img/menu.png)}
Enyone?
Thanks

Comment: made a change and found an answer to my problem! nope it will help to someone.
    background-image:   url(images/menu.png);
    background-repeat:  no-repeat;
    position:           absolute;
    background-size:    300px;
    height:             100%;
    width:              100%;

and you can change value of background-size using javascript or jquery ( .attr({ 'style':'background-size:150px auto; left:50px; top:50px;' }) )

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue. I resolved it with **just CSS**.

Basically `Object-fit: cover` helps you achieve the task of maintaining the aspect ratio while positioning an image inside a div.

But the problem was `Object-fit: cover` was not working in IE and it was taking 100% width and 100% height and aspect ratio was distorted. In other words image zooming effect wasn't there which I was seeing in chrome.

The approach I took was to position the image inside the container with  **absolute** and then **place it right at the centre** using the combination:

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Once it is in the centre, I give to the image,

```
// For vertical blocks (i.e., where height is greater than width)
height: 100%;
width: auto;

// For Horizontal blocks (i.e., where width is greater than height)
height: auto;
width: 100%;
```

This makes the image get the effect of Object-fit:cover.

---

## Here is a demonstration of the above logic.

https://jsfiddle.net/furqan_694/s3xLe1gp/

This logic works in all browsers.

Comment: The downside of this method is that when the real image size is smaller than it's container, the image is not expanded to fill the container.

Comment: Are you sure? Because the `height:100%` and/or `width:100%` fills the container to entire height and width respectively. If you could share a jsfiddle link, it will help understand the limitation you have in mind.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<style>
#foo, #bar{
    width: 50px; /* use any width or height */
    height: 50px;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
</style>

<div id="foo" style="background-image: url('path/to/image1.png');">
<div id="bar" style="background-image: url('path/to/image2.png');">
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2v3rdb48/)

...And if you want to set or change the image (using #foo as an example):

jQuery:

```
$("#foo").css("background-image", "url('path/to/image.png')");
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("foo").style.backgroundImage = "url('path/to/image.png')";
```

Answer (score 1):

Many of the solutions found here have some limitation: some not working in IE ( object-fit) or older browsers, other solutions do not scale up the images (only shrink it), many solution do not support resize of the window and many are not generic, either expect fix resolution or layout(portrait or landscape)

If using javascript and jquery is not a problem I have this solution based on the code of @Tatu Ulmanen. I fixed some issues, and added some code in case the image is loaded dinamically and not available at begining. Basically the idea is to have two different css rules and apply them when required: one when the limitation is the height, so we need to show black bars at the sides, and othe css rule when the limitation is the width, so we need to show black bars at the top/bottom.

```
function applyResizeCSS(){
    var $i = $('img#imageToResize');
    var $c = $i.parent();
    var i_ar = Oriwidth / Oriheight, c_ar = $c.width() / $c.height();  
    if(i_ar > c_ar){
        $i.css( "width","100%");
        $i.css( "height","auto");          
    }else{
        $i.css( "height","100%");
        $i.css( "width","auto");
    }
}   
var Oriwidth,Oriheight;
$(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        applyResizeCSS();
    });

    $("#slide").load(function(){
        Oriwidth  = this.width,
        Oriheight = this.height; 
        applyResizeCSS();
    }); 

    $(window).resize();
});
```

For an HTML element like:

```
<img src="images/loading.gif" name="imageToResize" id="imageToResize"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

HTML:

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
background-image: url("...");
background-size: 100%;
background-position: center;
}
```