# How to auto-resize an image while maintaining aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, image, aspect-ratio

How do you auto-resize a large image so that it will fit into a smaller width `div` container whilst maintaining its `width`:`height` ratio?

---

Example: stackoverflow.com - when an image is inserted onto the editor panel and the image is too large to fit onto the page, the image is automatically resized.

Comment: Some interesting libraries for doing image resizing to fit the container: * http://plugins.jquery.com/project/myimgscale
* http://code.google.com/p/jquery-imagefit-plugin/

Comment: Aside @Kevin's answer... You can also use services like ImageBoss to create your images with the size you want, on-demand. Fitting the image on the container is great but serving images responsively is way batter.

Comment: Posible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891857/how-do-you-stretch-an-image-to-fill-a-div-while-keeping-the-images-aspect-rat

Comment: @jolumg Not quite; while there's a lot of overlap in some solutions, there are also many solutions that are not interchangeable, as that one is asking how to scale an image up, whereas this one is asking to scale an image down.

Answer (score 2462, accepted):

Do not apply an explicit width or height to the image tag. Instead, give it:

```
max-width:100%;
max-height:100%;
```

Also, `height: auto;` if you want to specify a width only.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/xwrvxser/1/

```css
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.portrait {
    height: 80px;
    width: 30px;
}

.landscape {
    height: 30px;
    width: 80px;
}

.square {
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
}
```

```html
Portrait Div
<div class="portrait">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkF9Q.jpg">
</div>

Landscape Div
<div class="landscape">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkF9Q.jpg">
</div>

Square Div
<div class="square">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkF9Q.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: This will not scale both the height and width.

Comment: height: auto; if you want to specify a width only

Comment: Not applying explicit width and height to the image has the side-effect that the page will not reserve space to the image, and the page will flicker or content might jump as the image loads.

Answer (score 720):

It turns out there's another way to do this: [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit).

```
<img style='height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: contain'/>
```

will do the work. Don't forget to include other necessary attributes like `src` and `alt`, of course.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mbHB4/7364/

Comment: This will scale the image to fit the larger dimension completely within the container, so the smaller dimension may not cover it completely. To crop the larger dimension instead, use `object-fit: cover`

Comment: object-fit: cover worked for me, but now sure why ??

Answer (score 122):

Currently there is no way to do this correctly in a deterministic way, with fixed-size images such as JPEGs or PNG files.

**To resize an image proportionally, you have to set *either* the height or width to "100%", but not both.** If you set both to "100%", your image will be stretched.

Choosing whether to do height or width depends on your image and container dimensions:

1. If your image and container are both "portrait shaped" or both "landscape shaped" (taller than they are wide, or wider than they are tall, respectively), then it doesn't matter which of height or width are "%100".
2. If your image is portrait, and your container is landscape, you must set `height="100%"` on the image.
3. If your image is landscape, and your container is portrait, you must set `width="100%"` on the image.

If your image is an SVG, which is a variable-sized vector image format, you can have the expansion to fit the container happen automatically.

You just have to ensure that the SVG file has none of these properties set in the `<svg>` tag:

```
height
width
viewbox
```

Most vector drawing programs out there will set these properties when exporting an SVG file, so you will have to manually edit your file every time you export, or write a script to do it.

Answer (score 98):

Here is a solution that will both vertically and horizontally align your img within a div without any stretching even if the image supplied is too small or too big to fit in the div.

The HTML content:

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  <img alt="Client Logo" title="Client Logo" src="Imagelocation" />
</div>
```

The CSS content:

```css
#myDiv
{
  height: 104px;
  width: 140px;
}
#myDiv img
{
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

The jQuery part:

```js
var logoHeight = $('#myDiv img').height();
    if (logoHeight < 104) {
        var margintop = (104 - logoHeight) / 2;
        $('#myDiv img').css('margin-top', margintop);
    }
```

Answer (score 69):

You have two ways of making the image responsive.

1. When an image is a background image.

   ```
   #container{
       width: 300px;
       height: 300px;
       background-image: url(https://images.fonearena.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Lenovo-p780-camera-sample-10.jpg);
       background-size: cover;
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       background-position: center;
   }

   <div id="container"><div>
   ```

   Run it [here](https://codepen.io/sirajalam049/pen/ppzQzW)

   But one should use `img` tag to put images as it is better than `background-image` in terms of **SEO** as you can write **keyword** in the `alt` of the `img` tag. So here is you can make the image responsive.
2. When image is in `img` tag.

   ```
   #container{
       max-width: 400px;
       overflow: hidden;
   }
   img{
       width: 100%;
       object-fit: contain;
   }

   <div id="container">
       <img src="https://images.fonearena.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Lenovo-p780-camera-sample-10.jpg" alt="your_keyword"/>
   <div>
   ```

   Run it [here](https://codepen.io/sirajalam049/pen/Rxbezw)

Comment: object-fit: contain did the trick, thank you.

Comment: For case 1. when an image is a background image for me  background-size: contain; did the trick.

Answer (score 60):

Make it simple!

Give the container a **fixed** `height` and then for the `img` tag inside it, set `width` and `max-height`.

```
<div style="height: 250px">
     <img src="..." alt=" " style="width: 100%;max-height: 100%" />
</div>
```

The difference is that you set the `width` to be 100%, not the `max-width`.

Answer (score 33):

You can set the image as the background to a div, and then use the [CSS background-size property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp):

```
background-size: cover;
```

It will *"Scale the background image to be as large as possible so that the background area is completely covered by the background image. Some parts of the background image may not be in view within the background positioning area"* -- [W3Schools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3Schools)

Answer (score 26):

There are several ways to fit the **image** to `<div>`.

```
img {
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

The CSS **object-fit** property is used to specify how an `<img>` or `<video>` should be resized to fit its container.

This property tells the content to fill the container in a variety of ways; such as "preserve that aspect ratio" or "stretch up and take up as much space as possible".

- fill - This is default. The image is resized to fill the given dimension. If necessary, the image will be stretched or squished to fit
- contain - The image keeps its aspect ratio, but is resized to fit within the given dimension
- cover - The image keeps its aspect ratio and fills the given dimension. The image will be clipped to fit
- none - The image is not resized
- scale-down - the image is scaled down to the smallest version of none or contain

You can find out more working samples [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp).

Answer (score 25):

Check out my solution: http://codepen.io/petethepig/pen/dvFsA

It's written in pure CSS, without any JavaScript code.
It can handle images of any size and any orientation.

Given such HTML:

```
<div class="image">
  <div class="trick"></div>
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/415/200"/>
</div>
```

the CSS code would be:

```
.image {
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;  /* Container's dimensions */
  height: 150px;
}
img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.trick {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: This is actually nice. You can use :before pseudo-element to avoid extra .trick element

Answer (score 15):

I have much better solution without need of any JavaScript. It is fully responsive, and I use it a lot. You often need to fit an image of any aspect ratio to a container element with a specified aspect ratio. And having whole this thing fully responsive is a must.

```css
/* For this demo only */
.container {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.img-frame {
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  background: #ee0;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

/* This is for responsive container with specified aspect ratio */
.aspect-ratio {
  position: relative;
}
.aspect-ratio-1-1 {
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}
.aspect-ratio-4-3 {
  padding-bottom: 75%;
}
.aspect-ratio-16-9 {
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}

/* This is the key part - position and fit the image to the container */
.fit-img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 80%;
  max-height: 90%
}
.fit-img-bottom {
  top: auto;
}
.fit-img-tight {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="aspect-ratio aspect-ratio-1-1 img-frame">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300" class="fit-img" alt="sample">
  </div>

  <div class="aspect-ratio aspect-ratio-4-3 img-frame">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300" class="fit-img fit-img-tight" alt="sample">
  </div>

  <div class="aspect-ratio aspect-ratio-16-9 img-frame">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400" class="fit-img" alt="sample">
  </div>

  
  <div class="aspect-ratio aspect-ratio-16-9 img-frame">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x400" class="fit-img fit-img-bottom" alt="sample">
  </div>
  
</div>
```

You can set max-width and max height independently; the image will respect the smallest one (depending on the values and aspect ratio of the image). You can also set image to be aligned as you want (for example, for a product picture on an infinite white background you can position it to center bottom easily).

Answer (score 13):

This solution doesn't stretch the image and fills the whole container, but it cuts some of the image.

HTML:

```
 <div><img src="/images/image.png"></div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10em;
    overflow: hidden;

img {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

I just published a jQuery plugin that does exactly what you need with a lot of options:

https://github.com/GestiXi/image-scale

Usage:

HTML

```
<div class="image-container">
    <img class="scale" data-scale="best-fit-down" data-align="center" src="img/example.jpg">
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(function() {
    $("img.scale").imageScale();
});
```

Answer (score 11):

I see that many people have suggested **object-fit** which is a good option. But if you want it to work in **older browsers as well**, there is another way of doing it easily.

It's quite simple. The approach I took was to position the image inside the container with **absolute** and then **place it right at the centre** using the combination:

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Once it is in the centre, I give to the image,

```
// For vertical blocks (i.e., where height is greater than width)
height: 100%;
width: auto;

// For horizontal blocks (i.e., where width is greater than height)
height: auto;
width: 100%;
```

This makes the image get the effect of `object-fit:cover`.

---

#### Here is a demonstration of the above logic.

https://jsfiddle.net/furqan_694/s3xLe1gp/

This logic works in all browsers.

Answer (score 10):

The following works perfectly for me:

```
img{
   height: 99999px;
   object-fit:contain;
   max-height: 100%;
   max-width: 100%;    
   display: block;
   margin: auto auto;
}
```

Comment: It also works perfectly for me as well. Not sure how the commands work together in this case @Chong Lip Phang, especially how `height: 99999px` is used? I removed it to see the effect and the horizontal centering failed, so it appears that there is no redundancy.

Comment: @Vass height:99999px basically tries to enlarge the image while preserving the aspect ratio (width: auto) until the vertical or horizontal bound is reached (max-height or max-width). I think you can also use height:200%; or width:999vw.

Comment: While using grid (grid template areas), I found that including `overflow-y: hidden;` in the upper level div of the grid area to be necessary in a situation I am facing

Answer (score 10):

A simple solution is to use [Flexbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout). Define the container's CSS to:

```
.container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* Any custom height */
}
```

Adjust the contained image width to 100% and you should get a nice centered image in the container with the dimensions preserved.

Comment: It works perfectly in my case, `overflow: hidden` actually forced it to resize and shrink in height, but why? I was expecting it to just hide the part of image that was outside the boundary, but it actually forced the image to shrink to the actual proportions.

Answer (score 9):

I fixed this problem using the following code:

```html
<div class="container"><img src="image_url" /></div>
```

```css
.container {
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
}

.container img {
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: top;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Give the height and width you need for your image to the div that contains the <img> tag. Don't forget to give the height/width in the proper style tag.

In the <img> tag, give the `max-height` and `max-width` as 100%.

```
<div style="height:750px; width:700px;">
    <img alt="That Image" style="max-height:100%; max-width:100%;" src="">
</div>
```

You can add the details in the appropriate classes after you get it right.

Answer (score 7):

```
<style type="text/css">
    #container{
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 200px; /* Set height */
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        background-image: url('../assets/images/img.jpg');
        background-size: content; /* Scaling down large image to a div */
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
    }
</style>

<div id="container>
    <!-- Inside container -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

I centered and scaled proportionally an image inside a hyperlink both horizontally and vertically this way:

```
#link {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100px;
}
#link img {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-height: 60px;
    max-width: 60px;
}
```

It was tested in Internet Explorer, Firefox, and Safari.

More information about centering is [here](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center).

Answer (score 6):

The code below is adapted from previous answers and is tested by me using an image called `storm.jpg`.

This is the complete HTML code for a simple page that displays the image. This works perfect and was tested by me with www.resizemybrowser.com. Put the CSS code at the top of your HTML code, underneath your head section. Put the picture code wherever you want the picture.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #myDiv
            {
                  height: auto;
                  width: auto;
            }
            #myDiv img
            {
                max-width: 100%;
                max-height: 100%;
                margin: auto;
                display: block;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="myDiv">
            <img src="images/storm.jpg">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to tell the browser the height of where you are placing it:

```
.example {
    height: 220px; /* DEFINE HEIGHT */
    background: url('../img/example.png');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**Edit:** Previous table-based image positioning had issues in Internet Explorer 11 (`max-height` doesn't work in `display:table` elements). I've replaced it with inline based positioning which not only works fine in both Internet Explorer 7 and Internet Explorer 11, but it also requires less code.

---

Here is my take on the subject. It'll only work if the container has a specified size (`max-width` and `max-height` don't seem to get along with containers that don't have concrete size), but I wrote the CSS content in a way that allows it to be reused (add `picture-frame` class and `px125` size class to your existing container).

In CSS:

```
.picture-frame
{
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

.picture-frame.px125
{
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    line-height: 125px;
}

.picture-frame img
{
    margin-top: -4px; /* Inline images have a slight offset for some reason when positioned using vertical-align */
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 0; /* Remove border on images enclosed in anchors in Internet Explorer */
}
```

And in HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="picture-frame px125">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/lesa2wS.png"/>
</a>
```

### DEMO

```css
/* Main style */

.picture-frame
{
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

.picture-frame.px32
{
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 32px;
}

.picture-frame.px125
{
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    line-height: 125px;
}

.picture-frame img
{
    margin-top: -4px; /* Inline images have a slight offset for some reason when positioned using vertical-align */
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 0; /* Remove border on images enclosed in anchors in Internet Explorer */
}

/* Extras */

.picture-frame
{
    padding: 5px;
}

.frame
{
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<p>32px</p>
<a href="#" class="picture-frame px32 frame">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/lesa2wS.png"/>
</a>
<a href="#" class="picture-frame px32 frame">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/kFMJxdZ.png"/>
</a>
<a href="#" class="picture-frame px32 frame">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/BDabZj0.png"/>
</a>
<p>125px</p>
<a href="#" class="picture-frame px125 frame">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/lesa2wS.png"/>
</a>
<a href="#" class="picture-frame px125 frame">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/kFMJxdZ.png"/>
</a>
<a href="#" class="picture-frame px125 frame">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/BDabZj0.png"/>
</a>
```

---

Edit: Possible further improvement using JavaScript (upscaling images):

```
function fixImage(img)
{
    var $this = $(img);
    var parent = $this.closest('.picture-frame');
    if ($this.width() == parent.width() || $this.height() == parent.height())
        return;

    if ($this.width() > $this.height())
        $this.css('width', parent.width() + 'px');
    else
        $this.css('height', parent.height() + 'px');
}

$('.picture-frame img:visible').each(function
{
    if (this.complete)
        fixImage(this);
    else
        this.onload = function(){ fixImage(this) };
});
```

Comment: There is a drawback to using this method. If the image fails to load, alt text will be displayed with parent container `line-height`. If alt text has more than one line, it will start looking really bad...

Answer (score 6):

As [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27993140/1121352), you can also use `vh` units instead of `max-height: 100%` if it doesn't work on your browser (like Chrome):

```
img {
    max-height: 75vh;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[The accepted answer from Thorn007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029422/how-do-i-auto-resize-an-image-to-fit-a-div-container/3029434#3029434) doesn't work when **the image is too small**.

To solve this, I added a **scale factor**. This way, it makes the image bigger and it fills the div container.

Example:

```
<div style="width:400px; height:200px;">
  <img src="pix.jpg" style="max-width:100px; height:50px; transform:scale(4); transform-origin:left top;" />
</div>
```

Notes:

1. For WebKit you must add `-webkit-transform:scale(4); -webkit-transform-origin:left top;` in the style.
2. With a scale factor of 4, you have max-width = 400/4 = 100 and max-height = 200/4 = 50
3. An alternate solution is to set max-width and max-height at 25%. It's even simpler.

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution (4-step fix!!) that seems to work for me, is below. The example uses the width to determine the overall size, but you can also flip it to use the height instead.

1. Apply CSS styling to the image container (for example, <img>)
2. Set the width property to the dimension you want

   - For dimensions, use `%` for relative size, or autoscaling (based on image container or display)
   - Use `px` (or other) for a static, or set dimension
3. Set the height property to automatically adjust, based on the width
4. ENJOY!

For example,

```
<img style="width:100%; height:auto;"
    src="https://googledrive.com/host/0BwDx0R31u6sYY1hPWnZrencxb1k/thanksgiving.png"
/>
```

Answer (score 3):

All the provided answers, including the accepted one, work **only** under the assumption that the `div` wrapper is of a fixed size. So this is how to do it **whatever** the size of the `div` wrapper is and this is very useful if you develop a responsive page:

Write these declarations inside your **`DIV`** selector:

```
width: 8.33% /* Or whatever percentage you want your div to take */
max-height: anyValueYouWant /* (In px or %) */
```

Then put these declarations inside your **`IMG`** selector:

```
width: "100%" /* Obligatory */
max-height: anyValueYouWant /* (In px or %) */
```

**VERY IMPORTANT:**

The value of `maxHeight` must be the **same** for both the **`DIV`** and **`IMG`** selectors.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do this is by using `object-fit`:

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="path/to/image.jpg">
</div>

.container{
   height: 300px;
}

.container img{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

If you're using Bootstrap, just add the `img-responsive` class and change to

```
.container img{
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Bootstrap, you just need to add the `img-responsive` class to the `img` tag:

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="img_chania.jpg" alt="Chania">
```

*[Bootstrap Images](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_images.asp)*

Answer (score 2):

As seen in my 2014 [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/vsync/pen/DpmnK), I've made a solution that would work for any unknown combination of width/height (aspect-ratio) with the help of a as little javascript as possible, to change the CSS of how the image is centered when the aspect-ratio of the container changes above/below the aspect ratio of the image:

### Try resizing the container by dragging the bottom right corner:

```js
// Detects when the window width is too narrow for the current image 
// aspect-ratio, and fits it to height 100% instead of width 100%.
const photo = document.images[0]

const onPhotoResize = new ResizeObserver(entries => 
  window.requestAnimationFrame(checkRatio)
)

onPhotoResize.observe(photo.parentNode)

function checkRatio(){
  const photoParent = photo.parentNode,
        imageAspectRatio = photo.clientWidth / photo.clientHeight,
        parentAspectRatio = photoParent.clientWidth / photoParent.clientHeight
        
  photo.classList[imageAspectRatio > parentAspectRatio ? 'add':'remove']('max')
}
```

```css
.box{
  width: 20%;
  height: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0;
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 5px solid red;
 } 

.box > img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
}

.box > img.max{ width:auto; height:100%; }
```

```html
<div class='box'>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6a/Mona_Lisa.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is easy with a bit of maths...

Just put the image in a div and then in the HTML file where you specify the image. Set the width and height values in percentages using the pixel values of the image to calculate the exact ratio of width to height.

For example, say you have an image that has a width of 200 pixels and a height of 160 pixels. You can safely say that the width value will be 100%, because it is the larger value. To then calculate the height value you simply divide the height by the width which gives the percentage value of 80%. In the code it will look something like this...

```
<div class="image_holder_div">
    <img src="some_pic.png" width="100%" height="80%">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This was my solution. You will need to have the picture inserted twice. But it does not use js, and the img will resize to both width and height. You can click on 'run code snippet - full page', open dev console and resize window-width to see the responsive effect.

```css
    /* responsive width */
      .responsivewidth{
        background: lightsalmon;
        height: 100px;
        width: 50%;
      }
      /* Widthlimit */
      .maxedbywidth {
        background: navy;
        height: 200px;
        width: 100px;
      }
      .div1 {
        max-height: 100%;
        position: relative;
        box-sizing: content-box;

        /* Center: */
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
      }
      .margerimg {
        height: auto;
        max-width: 100%;
        opacity: 0;
      }
      .div2 {
        height: 100%;
        width: fit-content;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;

        /* Center: */
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
      }
      .mainimg {
        max-height: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
      }
```

```html
<div class="responsivewidth">
      <div class="div1">
        <img class="margerimg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/2000x1500" />
        <div class="div2">
          <img class="mainimg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/2000x1500" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="maxedbywidth">
      <div class="div1">
        <img class="margerimg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/2000x1500" />
        <div class="div2">
          <img class="mainimg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/2000x1500" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Having to insert the image twice (or four times in your actual demo) seems less than ideal compared to some of the other solutions here which just require a CSS property or three.

Comment: None of them worked for me *the way I need it to

Comment: I just felt like sharing my solution, maybe helping someone in the process. I actually think its a very nice bit of code you can apply as technique if you understand it. But I don't feel its right to criticise it, if you don't at least take the time to understand it. It's actually 2 pics u need

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer, *[Make an image responsive - simplest way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458650/make-an-image-responsive-simplest-way/36712112#36712112)* -

```
img{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 800px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This article may help you:

```css
  .square {
     position: relative;
     width: 300px;
     height: 300px;
     overflow: hidden;
  }
  img {
     position: absolute;
     max-width: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     transform: translate( -50%, -50%);
 }
  img.landscape {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
   <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/500" alt="Image" />
</div>
<div class="square">
   <img src="https://unsplash.it/500/400" class="landscape" alt="Image" />
</div>
```

*[Simple CSS Solutions: How to fit images with different dimensions in set containers](https://medium.com/@kimcodeashian/simple-css-solutions-how-to-resize-images-with-different-dimensions-without-cropping-eb744e93246d)* (2017-05-01)

```css
  .square {
     position: relative;
     width: 441px;
     height: 200px;
     overflow: hidden;
     border:1px solid black;
  }
  img {
     max-width: 100%;
/*     width: 100%;*/<----it stretch image and fit into the parent
     height: auto;
/*     transform: translate( -50%, -50%);*/<-----set vertically and horizontally center
 }
  img.landscape {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
   <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/08/28/12/32/man-5524488__340.jpg" alt="Image" />
</div>
```

Comment: Perhaps remove the outcommented CSS?

Comment: An explanation would be in order.