# What is the meaning of \9 in this width property value declaration?

Tags: css, width

What is the meaning of this? I am guessing it is a browser hack, but I have not been able to find what exactly it does.

```
width: 500px\9;
```

What is the significance of `\9`?

Comment: in a css file.. setting the width of some element.

Comment: doesn't appear to be valid in any CSS version, as far as I can see...

Comment: I don't think this question refers to the same thing.

Comment: @Shivan Raptor: No, it does not. It's a totally different question.

Answer (score 303, accepted):

`\9` is a "CSS hack" specific to Internet Explorer 7, 8, & 9.

This simply means that the one specific line of CSS ending with a `\9;` in place of the `;` is only valid in IE 7, 8, & 9.

In your example,

`width: 500px\9;` means that a width of 500 pixels (same result as `width: 500px;`) will only be applied while using IE 7, 8, & 9.

All other browsers will ignore `width: 500px\9;` entirely, and therefore not apply `width: 500px;` to the element at all.

If your CSS looked like this...

```
#myElement {
    width: 300px;
    width: 500px\9;
}
```

The result would be `#myElement` 500 pixels wide in IE 7, 8, & 9, while in all other browsers, `#myElement` would be 300 pixels wide.

[More info](https://web.archive.org/web/20160702085511/http://webdesignandsuch.com/ie9-specific-css-hack/)

---

**EDIT:**

This answer was written in 2011. It should now be noted that this hack also works in IE 10.

Comment: what would `width: 500px\6;` do?

Comment: @jdavid.net, if it doesn't break your CSS, absolutely nothing, AFAIK.

Comment: so there is a difference between `width: 500px\6;` and `width: 500px\9;` ?

Comment: @Sparky - I'm sorry, but your comment makes no sense. It should work on IE9 (only), and people report that it does, but for me it doesn't. I am asking why

Comment: @vsync, it does not follow the W3 spec so it's non-compliant code, a hack.  If other people report that it works on `background`, but it doesn't work only for you, then obviously something else must be wrong.  If you want help with your code, post a question.

Comment: @vsync, I only speak as if I'm responding to comments in the comment section.  Again, if `background` is working for others, then how could anyone know your answer?

Comment: `\0` instead of `\9` will apply it to IE10 as well

Comment: @abc123 lets hope they never get IE to version 16 then.

Comment: In my experience just now, ``\9`` was also applying to IE 10 with a ``width`` property, at least in IE's emulation mode.  Emulation mode is buggy at the best of times, so perhaps that's why.

Comment: @davidjb, that's because it's not really an emulator.   It was designed as a fallback for older code.

Comment: Just one extra note on this: If you use some tool like Sprockets(from Rails) that minifies the CSS this hack may break your build.

Comment: What is the significance of the number 9? Is it just an arbitrary number? Is it required for the hack to work?

Comment: @ChrisBier, I believe it's fairly apparent that since this is an Explorer hack, the "9" signifies the Explorer version.  Does it work without the `9`?  Since this is a "hack" that does not follow the W3C standard, it's impossible to predict where/when/how this works.

Comment: @Sparky the reason that I ask about the number is because I'm guessing the browser doesn't care about the number itself. For instance, does IE9 say "oh there's a 9 there that must be for me"? I am guessing that it is not the case being that it is a hack, so I am wondering if 9 is an arbitrary number.

Comment: @ChrisBier *"does IE9 say "oh there's a 9 there that must be for me"?"* ~ Of course it does or this hack would not work at all.   If you think it's an arbitrary number, then try it and verify.

Answer (score 13):

It's a css hack for IE9 & below version

write like this:

```
width: 500px\9;
```

Read this article http://dimox.net/personal-css-hacks-for-ie6-ie7-ie8/

Comment: Thanks for the link, but the article does not explain WHAT it does.

Comment: We use hack for IE for two things. 1) there are some properties which is not supported by IE like display:inline-block & 2) Every browser render some HTML & css properties differently. check this article http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/

Comment: Check link also http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/06/07/the-principles-of-cross-browser-css-coding/

Comment: IE does support display: inline-block;, bad example.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a particularly useful hack for the 'width' property, however.  At least not outside of quirks mode.

Comment: @reisio; read my comment carefully is also said display: inline-block is not support by IE.

Comment: display: inline-block; /IS/ supported by IE.

Comment: @reisio, depending on version it is only partially supported. IE 7 and below cannot apply `inline-block` to "block-level" elements.

Comment: @eyelidlessness: glad you agree.

Answer (score 2):

In IE9 to set the width property you just add this hack.

e.g

```
.align {
    float:left;
    margin:5px;
    background-color:blue;
    width:65px;
    width:\9 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS Hack for IE9

```
/* Hack CSS IE9 */
.csshackie9 {color:#f00\9\0\;}
```

Comment: you should post more information aboiut what is this hack about instead of linking outside - if that blog is gone, then value of your answer would decrease. Additionally, not everyone speaks russian.

Comment: It would be better to provide some essential info in English, because link you have posted is to russian blog.

Comment: OP, you should tell yourself off and go and sit on the naughty step.