# Bootstrap based theme broken in IE10

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-10

http://metagraf.github.io has been behaving well in all tested browser until IE10 came along. The top menu is overlaying the entire page when viewed in IE10.
A screenshot of how the page looks in IE10 can be seen here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2897577/ie10.png
Any ideas on how to fix this?

regards Oskar

Comment: how to run Css into IE10 http://geekswithblogs.net/anirugu/archive/2013/03/02/how-to-write-css-only-for-internet-explorer--10.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So when I run the site in question in IE 10, yes indeed, the top menu does look buggy in IE 10.

The immediate source of the problem is the `img` in the navbar.

If you hit `F12` and use IE's developer toolbar, and then if you set the `width` property of the `img` from `auto` to just being un-checked (so that `auto` is no longer the value, the site all of the sudden looks normal.

Digging deeper into the issue, here's the `css` setting for `img` in bootstrap:

```
img {
  width: auto\9;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 0;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
```

Ok, so what in the world is `width: auto\9`?
Well, looks like it is an IE hack, but a hack that does not apply to IE 10.

1. [CSS \9 in width property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004765/css-9-in-width-property)
2. http://www.paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/

So as a quick fix, I suppose one thing you could do would be to set a custom `css` property 
on the `img` in the `navbar` that is exact about the width of the `img`.