# Tilde in CSS attribute value

Tags: html, css

I found some CSS like this:

```
margin-top: ~"-2px\9";
```

Can anyone tell me what it is and what it does?

Comment: Isn't that LESS?

Comment: a hack about to be useless and break everything :p

Comment: It can be use as attribute selector though.

Comment: http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/general-discussions/new-css-error-in-kendo-common-css-introduced-with-2013-1-514-build.aspx

Comment: The `\9` is a hack targetting IE8. It's really poor practice. Don't do it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004765/css-9-in-width-property

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> What is it?

A syntax error.

> What does it do?

Breaks your stylesheet.

---

As mentioned in the comments on your question, it may be LESS instead of CSS. In LESS, a tilde before a string literal outputs the string as-is, because it may be a syntax error in pure LESS. `\9` is [an IE hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004765/css-9-in-width-property). See [*Escaping*](http://lesscss.org/#-escaping).

Comment: does people write this intentionally ?? what is the purpose?

Comment: and the \9 is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004765/css-9-in-width-property

Comment: Please consider other areas of css, less, sass etc
This gentlemen is most likely seeing "Escaping" being used.

Answer (score 7):

It may be a LESS Syntax. But tilde character is used in CSS3 as well. E-g the below Syntax:

```
p ~ ul { background:#ff0; }
```

will target ul elements that are preceded by a p element with the same parent:

Answer (score 3):

In Less, this is called **"Escaping"**.

**Escaping** allows you to use any random string as a property value or variable value.

For example **~"value"** or **~'value'** will be used as is without changes being made, only exception is interpolation.

Link to Less Docs: http://lesscss.org/#escaping