# What does "outline: thin dotted \9" mean in CSS?

Tags: html, css

Here's my CSS. Can someone tell me what "outline: thin dotted \9" means ?

```
    select:focus,
    textarea:focus,
    input:focus,
    .uneditable-input:focus {
        border-color: rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.8);
        outline: 0;
        outline: thin dotted \9;
        /* IE6-9 */
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
    }
```

Comment: Possibly already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004765/css-9-in-width-property

Comment: Looks like hack to work in older versions of IE..

Comment: It means that the "\9" only makes it valid in IE9

Comment: @Adsy it's reported that it's for "Internet Explorer 7, 8, & 9" not only 9.

Comment: @thomasjaworski.com ahh fair enough, I knew it was somewhere on that line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That means that `outline: thin dotted \9;` online will be applied when the client uses IE6-9, what is also commented under that line (`/* IE6-9 */`)

In case your question wasn't primarily about the `\9`: The line `outline: thin dotted` causes your input to have a thin dotted outline when it's focussed.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wKxEV/) with outline applied.