# "\9" randomly pops up everywhere in .css file on debug

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

Occasionally when I open up Firefox in an ASP.NET MVC 4 project, I get warnings like:

```
Validation (CSS 3.0): "\9" is not a valid value for the "width" property.
```

When this happens, "\9" is inserted into the .css file in totally random places.  For instance,

```
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {  
   display: block;  
   width: 100% \9;  
   max-width: 100%;  
   height: auto;  
}
```

This forces me to manually delete all instances of "\9" from the .css file.  What's going on?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004765/css-9-in-width-property

Comment: yeah, that answers my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\9` is a "CSS hack" specific to Internet Explorer 7, 8, & 9.

[Reference](http://dimox.net/personal-css-hacks-for-ie6-ie7-ie8/)