# Difference between \9 and \0 css hack

Tags: html, css

Could someone clear what are the diffrence b/w /9 and /0 css hacks. I thought /9 is for late ie 10 browser and /0 for late ie-8. But i noticed /9 works for ie8-ie10 and /0 works for ie8 to ie11 browsers. This is quite strange to me.

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border:#000 solid 1px;
    height: 300px\9;
    width: 300px\9;
    background: pink\0; 


}
```

i am looking at standard ie11 browser and its document mode.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004765/css-9-in-width-property

Comment: I already checked it..it shows /9 works for ie7 to ie9 not for ie10. but i found it also work for ie10. And /0 also worked in ie11.

Comment: Check this website http://browserhacks.com/