# Compiling Error Bootstrap Less with gulp?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, compilation, less, gulp

I'm using:

- Bootstrap v3.1.1 with Less
- Gulp with less@1.7.5

forms.less:

```
line-height: @line-height-base ~"\0";
```

style.css:

```
line-height: 1.42857143 \0;
```

1. what means the statement ~"\0" ?
2. what goes wrong?

Thanks a lot for your attention.

Comment: This is not a error. This is what it is supposed to be compiled to. See [(1)](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bless%5d%20escap*) (not counting that in modern Less compilers this is no longer necessary for `\\` as they can understand  it properly).

Comment: `\0` -> same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004765