# Bootstrap v3.3 has unusual line-height

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

The latest compiled css for Bootstrap V3.3.0 (and at least the previous version) contains some unusual syntax for the line-height in a few places. Can anyone explain it? Needless to say, it causes Resharper to spit the dummy...

```
input[type="month"] {
  line-height: 34px;
  line-height: 1.42857143 \0; <<<-- here. the '\0' is what bothers me
}
```

You will find it around line 2408 in the css.

Also noteworthy is the repeat definition, with and without units. What browser 'feature' does this rectify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14006) and [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004765/css-9-in-width-property)

Its a CSS hack specific to IE, it will only apply to IE10 and under. \9 would apply to IE9 and under etc... All other browsers will ignore it and keep 34px line-height.

Comment: Excellent work. I searched BS and did not find that. I missed the SO question as it was not tagged with Bootstrap. I should have been more general.