# Stylus keep "\9" CSS IE9 hack

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, stylus

I'm trying to write an IE9 rule only ([width: 40px\9;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004765/css-9-in-width-property)) in Stylus, but it seems that Stylus keeps removing the `\9` part and turns it into a whitespace character instead. I've tried various combinations of `\` and `/`, but to no avail.

For example

```
width 40px\\9;
```

compiles to

```
width: 40px \ 9;
```

Does anyone know how to make stylus keep the `\` as a literal "\" and not turn it into a whitespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`unquote`](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/bifs.html#unquotestr--ident):

```
width unquote('40px\9')
```

yields

```
width: 40px\9;
```

Answer (score -1):

This approach does not only apply to Internet Explorer 9; this hack affects also Internet Explorer 8, and 10. These three versions of Internet Explorer doesn't require the same solutions to certain layout problems, and as a result, this approach is likely to create more problems than it solves.

Microsoft has provided a method for applying browser-specific styles via the use of conditional comments. This is the means by which you should do browser-specific alteration is needed — please avoid CSS hacks.

To target Internet Explorer 9, use the following conditional comments:

```html
<!--[if IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ie9fixes.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Although the above will likely help you resolve your issue more quickly, the *correct* approach is to ensure that a workaround is even necessary. Make sure that your markup and CSS are valid. More often than not browser-specific problems are the result of invalid code.

Support for conditional comments was dropped in Internet Explorer 10.