# How to write \9 IE8 hack inside Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-8

When using normal CSS stylesheet I just use such code:

```
display:inline;
display:block\9;
```

and it works instantly.

But when I got the same code inside JavaScript it just doesn't work making whole input field invisible. How the \9 hack for IE8 should be entered ?

```
inp.style.display="inline";
inp.style.display="block\9";
```

Comment: what is `\9` supposed to do and when would you use it?

Comment: ^^ agreed. I've never heard of/apparently needed this.

Comment: @charlietfl: Apparently it makes IE9 read it [according to this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8004962/3436942) - but still can't think of a use case

Comment: Can't imagine a use case for elements needing to be block in IE but inline in other browsers. Even if it was needed, only way I could see doing this with script is in a style tag

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the backslash because it's a special character in strings:

```
inp.style.display = 'block\\9';
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `\9 hack`. Maybe it only works when it's reading the CSS file, not in style attributes.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that JS is interpreting the "\9" as a literal "9" and you are really ending up with `inp.style.display="block9";`.

To fix this, use a double backslash:

`inp.style.display="block\\9";`

Not tested, but it's something to try.

Comment: I am trying it in Chrome and apparently it's detecting that `block\9` is not a valid value for `display` and not applying it to the element. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Some [context about the `\9`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004765/css-9-in-width-property) CSS hack.

I'd advise you against using hacks for IE9 as this is the last version of IE considering conditional comments.
[Conditional classes](http://www.paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/) are a better practice imho, more robust or future-proof.

Otherwise [Browserhacks](http://browserhacks.com) is a great resource when you've to use one those dreaded hacks. Filter for IE 9 and you'll have hacks using JS properties for IE6-10 or 8-10 or 9 only, etc.
The CSS hacks proved reliable when I had to use them (sigh), I didn't test the JS ones.