# CSS Terminology: What are these values called in CSS quotes property?

Tags: html, css, terminology

What is the actual term for the following values of the quotes property? I tried searching but couldn't find anything other than [IE \9 CSS hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004765/css-9-in-width-property), so please let me know the terminology and the use behind it, that would be really great.

```
blockquote {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  border-left: 10px solid #ccc;
  margin: 1.5em 10px;
  padding: 0.5em 10px;
  quotes: "\201C""\201D""\2018""\2019";
}
```

Comment: You mean the character entities? http://brajeshwar.github.io/entities/

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `quotes:` CSS allows you to substitute a symbol for the open and closed quotes used within the page. See [this reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_quotes.asp) for more information.

> The first two values specifies the first level of quotation embedding, the next two values specifies the next level of quote embedding, etc

In your example they are using the [Unicode Character References](http://unicode-table.com/en/).

Answer (score 1):

As per the [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_quotes.asp) page:

> Specify the quotation marks for quotations

And as per the question about the content of the property, those are `escaped unicode` characters.

You will see those quotes when you use `<blockquote></blockquote>` elements inside your page.

Comment: Yeah right, but what are those values with backslashes? such as \201C, what are those called? and where do we use them?

Answer (score 1):

Those are Unicode character codes.
If you want to get specific in what they are (codes, numbers, ID's) See:

[Wikipedia: Unicode Architecture_and_terminology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#Architecture_and_terminology)