# align images according to browser size

Tags: html, css

[Check this image](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/34586898/1024.jpg)
This is a normal image with 1024px browser window
now if the browser size is reduced below 1024px, the images and the text block needs to gradually wrap as shown below. 
[Check this](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/34586898/480.jpg)
How should we achieve this.I mean what tag we need in CSS for achieving this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684304/how-can-i-resize-an-image-dynamically-with-css-as-the-browser-width-height-chang

Comment: What you need is responsive webdesign. You can find more documentation [SmashingMagazine: Responsive Web Design](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/)

Comment: Thanks a lots...it was really helful...!!!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to make images to wrap is to just put `img` elements in an HTML document in succession watch them wrap. What you need to add to this to achieve a specific layout depends on what that specific layout is. This might involve different style sheets for different ranges of window width, using media queries.