# Jquery: Dynamic image width and height on browser resize

Tags: jquery

I have an image that i want to fit in the browser window.
The width and the height should not be more than the window width and height.

I have made an function that works for the width but not for the height at the same time.

[Se my JS BIN](http://jsbin.com/ugiher/1/edit) and drag the browser window up and down right to left and the proportions is wrong

Comment: check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684304/how-can-i-resize-an-image-dynamically-with-css-as-the-browser-width-height-chang

Comment: That only makes the image responsive for the width.
In an ordinary site that would be the answer. 

But I'm only showing 1 image on my site and nothing else.
So what I want is to make the image max-height and max-width. The image can't be wider or higher then the browser window and have to be in the right propotions.

Answer (score 0):

Try

CSS:

```
img { 
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

this will make the image smaller if the container where the image is placed gets smaller than the image is.

And an UL-Element requires LI-Child-elements.

Comment: Merec: Thanks for your reply. I have tried that, but that did not work. I can't find any solution regarding my problem. So I decided to skip max-height.

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery code `$("#book li img")` will not work as there is no `li` inside your `ul` element.

I hope this is what you are looking for

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/uyuziv/2/edit)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Oh sorry! My misstake. Offcourse there is a <li>-tag inside my <ul>.
Missed to write that in my question.

Your fiddle did not work as expected. The image must have the right proportions.

Comment: @Claes yes I do understand what you are trying to do here. but it seems not possible with `img` tags. you should try `background-size: 100% 100%` keeping the image as `background-image` instead of `img` here. This is purely my opinion.