# I'm trying to remove the scroll from the page, I do not understand what I'm doing wrong

Tags: html, css

I want the page to look like the second image.I thought that with the overflow it would be enough to hide the rest of the image

This is the result:

[image]

This is what I want

[image]

```css
.bgMentor{
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 overflow:hidden;
 position:absolute;

  }
  
  .bgMentor img{
   min-width: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 top:50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
  }
```

```html
<div class="bgMentor">
       <img class="img-responsive" src="{{Storage::url('img/getamentor.png')}}"> 
      </div>
```

Comment: You need to provide a link to running code.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16217355/automatically-resize-images-with-browser-size-using-css) might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a top and left value for your position: absolute element

```
.bgMentor{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;


    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `overflow-y: hidden;` instead of just `overflow:;`. If that doesn’t work, try putting the `<Img>` directly in the body and stylize it using a `class=“bgMentor”`.