# Resizing an image based on browser size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to resize a background image on my Square space website (link [here](http://www.worldsofepoch.com/custom-carousel-test/?rq=carousel)) based on the size of the user's browser window. More specifically, if the user's window size drops below a certain width then the image adjusts to a smaller size and maintains its aspect ratio.

This seems to be a common issue. I've been digging for hours now and can't seem to find a solution. I'm using JavaScript to do the work, but it won't get it done.

Mind you all, I'm talking about something different than fluid resizing (i.e. using percentage values).

I've run this code through a quality validation and it came back with no syntax errors. So beyond this, I'm lost.

I injected this (jQuery) script into the page header:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    function imageresize() {
        var contentwidth = $(window).width();
        if ((contentwidth) < 1500) {
            $(".widescreen").attr("height", "480px");
        } else {
            $(".widescreen").attr("height", "768px");
        }
    }
    imageresize(); //Triggers when document first loads    

    $(window).on("resize", function() {
        imageresize();
    });
});
```

```css
.widescreen {
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/96pxGnd.jpg) center top no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  margin-left: -50vw;
  margin-right: -50vw;
  height: 768px;
  /* Trying to change this value so the rest of the CSS adjusts accordingly */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Is the syntax wrong? Please help! And thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you not want to use percentage values, if it works?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatically resize images with browser size using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16217355/automatically-resize-images-with-browser-size-using-css)

Comment: For a couple of reasons:

1. To keep some rigidity to the design
2. So I know how to change the design for different devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no height attribute for divs recognized by the browser so

```
$(".widescreen").attr("height", "480px");
```

is adding height="480px" tothe code but that doesn't tell it to render differently.

I think you want

```
$(".widescreen").css("height", "480px");
```

Comment: Holy crap, this made so much sense! Even better: it worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

you should use css media queries to check screen size and then set your desired styles [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) is a good tutorial for that also you can use bootstrap img-responsive class it is easier to use [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_css_images.asp)
you can find an example for that

Answer (score 0):

Try `media screen` for this!

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-device-width: 900px) {
  .image {
     width: 200px
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  .image {
     width: 500px
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <header>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=0.5,user-scalable=yes,initial-scale=1.0" />
  </header>
  <body>
    <img class="image" src="https://static.bhphotovideo.com/explora/sites/default/files/Correct.jpg" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

This issue can be resolved using the following code snippet in `CSS`, as it is better to use the `max-width` property for the images. This tag will use the percentage value for the width of the images.

Please add,

```
img {max-width:100%};
```