# Dynamically sized images

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a responsive image to a front page that expands to the full width of the page. Similar to what many sliders do, but I only have one image so a slider is overkill. I've set up a div and set it's background image and background-size to 100% and that achieves the width. My problem is the height. I have to use a fixed height in order for the div to appear. I've tried setting height to auto, but then I don't get an image. I tried using this method:

[How can I resize an image dynamically with CSS as the browser width/height changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684304/how-can-i-resize-an-image-dynamically-with-css-as-the-browser-width-height-chang)

but I can't seem to get the width to scale correctly. Using a fix height works fine until the browser window expands past the size of the image, and then it starts to cut off. Any thoughts on how I can make the height scale dynamically just as the width? Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

My code:

CSS:

```
.banner {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 720px;
    background: url(../images/homepagebanner.jpg) no-repeat left top;
    background-size: 100%;

}
```

HTML5:

```
<div class="banner"></div>
```

I am using bootstrap, but this is outside of a container so it shouldn't be affecting this piece of code.

EDIT Here's the codepen:
http://cdpn.io/xLvzA

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the height of html to 100%, then setting the height of your banner to 100%? Adding a codepen demo to show your exact issue might help a bit better to help vizualize the exact problem you're having

Comment: Yeah, that was my first thought. Setting the height of the banner to 100% makes the image disappear. I updated the question with a codepen link. Thanks for the help!

Comment: it might be best to just use a static image in this case

Comment: I may fall back to that, but it seems like there's a solution that is evading me. I'm helping a design student out and she really wants that dynamic picture. Thanks for the help.