# How do I make images fit the entire screen fully, regardless of screen size?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a horizontally scrollable website. I took screenshots of my clients demo website, and labeled them out as images 1-8. To make the site scrollable horizontally I put all the images in a div and set no-wrap property. The problem is: Each image is too big for my screen. I want each image to perfectly fit the size of my view port. My question is: How do I make each image fit the entire screen fully, regardless of screen size?

HTML:

```
<html>  
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <script src="jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.scrollpath.js"></script>
    <script src="createScroll.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="scrollable">
      <img src="1.png"></img> 
      <img src="2.png"></img>
      <img src="4.png"></img>
      <img src="5.png"></img>
      <img src="6.png"></img>
      <img src="7.png"></img>
      <img src="8.png"></img>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#scrollable {
  display: inline;
  white-space:nowrap;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: Could this help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684304/how-can-i-resize-an-image-dynamically-with-css-as-the-browser-width-height-chang

Comment: the `float: left;` and `display:inline` is not needed for the parent DIV element.

Comment: also the closing `</img> ` tag is useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, use `vh` with `max-height`:

CSS:

```
#scrollable {
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

img {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

**See JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/48ck23L9/4/**

**Note that the second image is originally smaller than the viewport.**

Comment: This won't work if the image is smaller than the screen.

Comment: also without 100vh: http://jsfiddle.net/48ck23L9/5/ 100% the 100% absolute container is enough

Comment: cool! that's probably better supported by non-html5 browsers too =)

Answer (score 1):

If you want something really **responsive** I'd go with **DIV** elements and **background** images. It's about images after all.

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/vukib/1/edit?html,css,output)** (resize to see the magic!)

```
<div id="scrollable">
  <div style="background-image: url(1.jpg);"></div>
  <div style="background-image: url(2.jpg);"></div>
  <div style="background-image: url(3.jpg);"></div>
</div>
```

The Simple CSS:

```
#scrollable{
  height:100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#scrollable > div{
  background: none 50% / cover;
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin-right:-4px;
}
```

Note: Usign this technique as you can clearly see the images will be cropped-to-fit but every image will do exactly what you asked for:

> I want each image to perfectly fit the size of my view port. My question is: How do I make each image **fit the entire screen fully**, regardless of screen size?

<sub>Otherwise, if you want to preserve the whole image, than the answer is banally simple. make it **100% height** the container area.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `vh` and `vw` units.

```
img {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}
```

Comment: this stretches the image to the viewport size so that the image will skew.

Comment: Well, yes, that's literally what the question is asking for though.  The question is asking for all images to fit to the browser window, "regardless of screen size".  That means sometimes images will have to be skewed.