# div height based on background image

Tags: jquery, css

I need to set the height of `<div>` based on background image which is contained, could anybody help me how to do that? In the div is some text.

I would live either a help how to achieve that in my code in [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/GFuF3YL6wp) or any other approach how to achieve that would be also great.

I've found this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684304/how-can-i-resize-an-image-dynamically-with-css-as-the-browser-width-height-chang) already, but it didn't worked for my - it's used in bootstrap template used for a Wordpress. Thanks a lot!

Code:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="uvod">
    <div class="row clearfix uvod silver"><div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-12 column">
            <div class="text-center"><h2>HEADER 2</h2></div>
            <div class="text">Some text goes here.</div>
        </div>
    </div></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.uvod {
    background:url('http://disk.kybernaut.cz/header.png') no-repeat top center;
    height: 550px;
    padding-top: 250px;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Comment: Do you mind if `<img> ` is used

Comment: Actually, no, but it has to be on the right place :) And it has to determine height of whole section `.container-fluid` (it's one page design).

Comment: I was talking about something like this http://jsfiddle.net/akshay7/vet2tq5e/

Comment: But how to cover it on the whole width and there needs to be a text over it.

Comment: Try something like https://jsfiddle.net/7r2gv3k8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```js
var container = $(".uvod");
var url = container
          .css("background")
          .split(/\s/)
          .map(function(value) {
            return /url/.test(value) 
            ? value.replace(/url\(|\)/g, "")
            : null
          }).filter(Boolean)[0];


var img = new Image;
img.onload = function() {
  container.height(this.height);
  console.log(container.height());
};
img.src = url;
```

```css
.uvod {
    background:url('http://disk.kybernaut.cz/header.png') no-repeat top center;
   /* height: 550px; */
    padding-top: 250px;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="container-fluid" id="uvod">
    <div class="row clearfix uvod silver"><div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-12 column">
            <div class="text-center"><h2>HEADER 2</h2></div>
            <div class="text">Some text goes here.</div>
        </div>
    </div></div>
</div>
```

See [.height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/)

Comment: In Chrome console it returns me: "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a functionscripts.js?ver=4.1.1:10 (anonymous function)" Some issue of Wordpress? Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: Try substituting `jQuery` for `$` at $(".uvod");` -> `jQuery(".uvod");` ?

Comment: Helped, but: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefinedscripts.js?ver=4.1.1:12 (anonymous function)`

Comment: Hm, still the same error. I'm not good in jquery, but are you sure that you get in 'split' correct value?

Comment: Is `undefinedscripts.js?ver=4.1.1:12` a file loaded at page ? Is `js` file named `undefined` , or "undefined" ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I've copied that and it got mixed together: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined` and `scripts.js?ver=4.1.1:31` (that point on the line with split function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73536/discussion-between-guest271314-and-kybernaut-cz).

Comment: What does `console.log(container, container.css("background"))` return ?

Comment: I'm in chat, sorry. It returns `undefined`