# keep/change uploaded image size

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-ui-resizable

I want to put uploaded images in such a way that if the image size is smaller than container div, it keeps its original size, but if the image size is larger than container div then it fits in the div and I have to provide width and height to the image else jquery.resizable will not work.
Is there any possible way ?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029422/image-auto-resize-to-fit-div-container)

Comment: make sure u keep the aspect ratio.

Comment: for example you might want to take a look at powerpoint add image functionality, I want to create exactly same in HTML. Hope this clarifies my question

Comment: Found exactly what I was looking for here : [Solution][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can use max-height and max-width.

```
.imgClass{

 max-height: container-height;
 max-width: container-width;
}
```

Comment: I get the basic idea, but I don't think it would work in my case
my structure is something like
<div id='container'> <!--This is resizable and draggable-->
 <img/> <!--here it could be an image or a video or flash or chart-->
</div>

so if I make max-width and max-height as 100% then it keeps the aspect ratio while 
resizing, which I don't want. Resize should be fluid

Comment: do you want to cover entire parent ? if so you have t use jQuery/JavaScript and you image may look distorted as aspect ratio will not be maintained.

Comment: for example you might want to take a look at powerpoint add image functionality, I want to create exactly same in HTML. Hope this clarifies my question

Comment: max-height and max-width will get applied only if image width or height exceed the container height otherwise it will appear as it original sape. sorry right now I don't have powerpoint on my system.