# How can I display portrait and landscape images in a carousel?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I use [Owl Carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/lazyLoad.html) to display images in a carousel with Javascript and jQuery. I have portrait and landscape images and with the CSS:

```
.owl-carousel {
  max-height: 80%;
  max-width: 90%;
  display:block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.owl-carousel img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

the landscape images respect the 100% limit on width and the full picture appears on screen; the portrait images **do not** respect the 100% limit on height and the picture appears in one or two screens, requiring scrolling down. I would like the portrait pictures to be resized and display completely on a screen with landscape orientation, just as I'd like landscape pictures to display completely on a screen with portrait orientation.

I have tried the solutions in [max-height AND max-width with CSS only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350278/max-height-and-max-width-with-css-only) to no avail. I have temporarily fixed the problem by including only landscape images ([live website](https://covoucher20.org/regions/obidos)).

How can I include portrait images in the carousel?

Comment: Hi https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/orientation, maybe this works?

Comment: @HalilÇakar As I understand that detects whether the viewport is in landscape or portrait. I updated the question with more details on what I want to achieve.

Comment: Oh i see, yea if you want to change images by viewport then just detect when they change, so maybe `window.addEventListener("orientationchange", yourToggleFunction);` and you can check via `screen.orientation.angle` and change your image path's ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The css [Object-Fit](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp) property is your friend here. This makes it so the longest part of the image always stays within the container bounds.

```
.owl-carousel img {
  display:block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

In your case, you might want to give the image parent `.owl-carousel` an actual size as well instead of setting just max sizes and using margins. Also, I suggest centering the image, not the container.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please add object-fit: cover; css and add fix height. try This

```
.owl-carousel img{
object-fit: cover;
height: 700px;}
```

Comment: I believe `object-fit: cover` scales the image up to fit the container, which would be useful for a background image. In this case `object-fit: contain` served for what I wanted: display the full image within a container.