# Make an image to fit its parent dimensions

Tags: css, html, image

I have some photos which have big sizes, I would like to set them to the Parent's dimension size. If one time the parent dimension is 1200x800, I would like to set the photo dimensions to 1200x800, but also I would like to see the **whole** image. If my parent dimension is 500x300, I would like the image to be 500x300 and so on.

Is this even possible? I want to shrink the image or expand it according to it's parent's dimension.

Thanks!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029422/how-do-i-auto-resize-an-image-to-fit-a-div-container

Comment: many answers say to use `img {max-width: 100%}` but it won't work if the size of the parent is set using max-: `.parent{max-width: 50%}`. I must be without max-: `.parent{width: 50%}`

Comment: How to do it with a parent of `max-width`,`max-height` but no `width` or `height` because it **must**(!) be able to dynamically shrink if the contents is not big enough?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

The css property that you want is `max-width` :

**Css**

```
img {
    max-width:100%;
}
```

You could add a container around your image and set `overflow:hidden` to prevent images to get bigger than the defined width/height.

Comment: alright! This one works! If you want to keep the aspect ratio, you should also use the max-height. Thanks

Comment: @kfirba i tried that, but it's taking the aspect ratio of the container, and not the image itself

Answer (score 20):

Use this bit of css to scale your image:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In general it might help to remember this:

1: A track is not a container.

2: A grid area is not a container.

3: A nested element is not a container **unless you declare it as such.**

Declarations such as *max-width: 100%, object-fit: contain* and so on describe how the element (e.g img) will behave inside its **container** - not inside the track or area it happens to have been placed in. And not inside the tag it lives in, nested inside its container. e.g after

HTML:

```
<div class="myContainer">
    <div class="myTopRow">
        <img src="myPic.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="myBottomRow">
        <span class="mySubText">Your subtext here.</span>
    </div>
</div>

CSS:
.myContainer {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows:  [row1Start] 1fr [row1End row2Start] 1fr [row2End];
    grid-template-columns: [col1Start] 1fr [col1End];
}

.myTopRow {
    grid-rows: row1Start / row1End;
    grid-columns: col1Start / col1End;    
}

.myBottomRow {
    grid-rows: row2Start / row2End;
    grid-columns: col1Start / col2End;
}

.myTopRow img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

you've made a grid consisting of one column and two rows. The image in the top row will seem to spill over into the second row, colliding with that row's spanned text. In reality there's no overflow - the image is not contained by the top row (which has not been declared as a container, but is "merely" an area spanning tracks). Within it's actual container (the whole two-row box) the image is perfectly contained.

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow, here is a suggestion to improve the post : you can add a language identifier to highlight the css and make it more readable.

Answer (score 5):

I might be naive, but isn't this as simple as this ?

```
img {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Well, does it matter if I add to this code also max-width and max-height? anyways, is this going to display the **whole** picture in the div?

Comment: Hmm it then depends on your image container... Try sharing a fiddle with some of the tips ;).

Comment: @kfirba actually yes, it does matter. Some browsers will not render the `max-` prefix values if no initial values have been set. it will ignore `max-width` if no `width` has been specified. This isn't so much just for images but for certain elements on certain browser types

Answer (score 4):

Try this in the image tag

```
<img src="url.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />
```

Or set the backgound of the element as the image and do the same.

Answer (score 3):

In the case the **image is bigger** than the parent container you have to set :

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

If your **image is smaller** you have to set instead

```
img {
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

otherwise it will just stay at its original width and height.
(the Height is set to *auto* by default)

Answer (score 2):

try to use the max-width property, this might give a bug in earlier versions IE though

```
#custom img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are cases where one is dealing with a wide array of images sizes where some might need to be scaled horizontally, others vertically, and some both. When using `max-[width|height]` properties the shortest dimension won't completely scale. That means:

- Images where `width` > `height`: there will be a vertical gap
- Images where `height` > `width`: there will be a horizontal gap

To address this issue, one can essentially scale both to fit and the `object-fit` property will allow the aspect ratio to magically stay the same:

```
.scaled-img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

To control the sizing, use a wrapper element and style appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

```
width: inherit;
height: inherit;
object-fit: contain;
```