# HTML/CSS width/height wont change?

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>HTML, CSS and JavaScript demo</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="profilepage.css">

</head>


<body>
  <!-- Start your code here -->

  <div class="profile-box">
    <div class="bg">
      <img src="https://www.capisol.co.za/wp-content/uploads/gaussian-blur-orange-367347-background-wallpapers.jpg" />
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- End your code here -->
</body>

</html>
```

profilepage.css

```
.bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
}
```

Comes out like this: on my page

[image]

What I want is the width to cover the entire first row and the height to be 10% of the page. i.e.

[image]

Where the black line ends the img

I've been playing with width and height forever bu nothing is working. The moment I change width something large comes up. Even if I let the width be less. I don't know why width is changing the height. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make the image a background image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Percentage heights refer to the height of the immediate parent. If the parent height is not set, the CSS will do nothing. You can either cascade a 100% height setting down from the body tag or you can apply some fixed value to the image tag's immediate parent.

**Fixed Value** (Uses view height to refer directly to height of the body tag)

```
<div style="height: 10vh;">
  <img style="max-height: 100%;" src="https://www.capisol.co.za/wp-content/uploads/gaussian-blur-orange-367347-background-wallpapers.jpg" />
</div>
```

**Cascading Height**

```
.bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}

.profile-box {
  height: 100%;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

img {
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

In both cases, we must restrict the image height by the parent class or no changes will take effect.

I used these sources:
[How to make a div 100% height of the browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/how-to-make-a-div-100-height-of-the-browser-window)
and
[Make an image to fit its parent dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15295697/make-an-image-to-fit-its-parent-dimensions)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, You need to define height and width of every element otherwise the css don't know which element have what value.

```
body, html {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            width: 100%; 
            height: 100%;
        }
        .profile-box {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .bg {
          width: 100%;
          height: 10%;
        }
        .bg img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
```