# Make an image responsive - the simplest way

Tags: html, css, image, mobile

I notice that my code is responsive, in the fact that if I scale it down to the size of a phone or tablet - all of the text, links, and social icons scale accordingly.

However, the ONLY thing that doesn't is my image in the body; which is wrapped in paragraph tags... with that being said, is there a simple way to make the image responsive as well?

Here's the code that I used to have my image show in the body:

```
<body>
    <center>
        <p><a href="MY WEBSITE LINK" target="_blank"><img src="IMAGE LINK" border="0" alt="Null"></a></p>
    </center>
</body>
```

Comment: we need to see some code

Comment: Just added it above in my question

Comment: I'm not sure I would call it a duplicate, since my code differs from his pretty heavily

Comment: But he was having the same issue

Comment: I was going to mark it as a duplicate of that until I realized someone else had already done so.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

You can try doing

```
<p>
  <a href="MY WEBSITE LINK" target="_blank">
    <img src="IMAGE LINK" style='width:100%;' border="0" alt="Null">
  </a>
</p>
```

This should scale your image if in a fluid layout.

For responsive (meaning your layout reacts to the size of the window) you can add a class to the image and use `@media` queries in CSS to change the width of the image.

Note that changing the height of the image will mess with the ratio.

Comment: It made my image HUGE lol, however it does scale down now. How can I have it keep it's original image dimensions?

Comment: add `max-width: 300px;` (for example) to it. and make it so it would the largest you want it be, this way it won't go beyond that

Comment: Thank you, great answer. Also, what did you mean by the @media ? If you could explain that a little more in depth (I just started coding 2  days ago).

Comment: here is some official docs for media queries http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/ and here is something which explains it better :) http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: I have one additional question in regards to adding the ((( style:'width:___%' ))), if one of my users happens to view my site from their 50 inch TV or large computer screen, my logo will end up taking up most of their screen, whereas before, the logo only stayed at its dimensions... the (((max-width: 300px;))) may work, I tried but I might have placed it in the wrong area since it didn't work.. Where would it go? Also, must I keep it at 100%?

Comment: first, the 100% part only depends on the original dimensions of the image. if the image is really big, you should either make it smaller (will load faster) or set it the max-width to lower. That css you should put on `img { .. }` or engulf the img in a container div and enforce max-width on that

Comment: should be `max-width: 100%;` for your images

Answer (score 63):

Width: 100% will break it when you view on a wider are.

Following is Bootstrap's `img-fluid`.

```
max-width: 100%; 
display: block; 
height: auto;
```

Answer (score 27):

I would also recommend to use all the CSS properties in a different file than the HTML file, so you can have your code organized better.

So to make your img responsive, I would do:

First, name your `<img>` tag using a `class` or `id` attribute in your HTML file:

```
<img src="IMAGE LINK" border="0" class="responsive-image" alt="Null">
```

Then, in my CSS file I would make the changes to make it responsive:

```
.responsive-image {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

To make all images on your website responsive, don't change your inline HTML from correct markup, as `width:100%` doesn't work in all browsers and causes problems in Firefox. You want to place your images on your website how you normally should:

```
<img src="image.jpg" width="1200px" height="600px" />
```

And then add to your CSS that any image max-width is 100% with height set to auto:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

That way your code works in all browsers. It will also work with custom CMS clients (i.e. Cushy CMS) that require images to have the actual image size coded into the inline HTML, and it is actually easier this way when all you need to do to make images responsive is simply state in your CSS file that the max-width is 100% with height set to auto. Don't forget `height: auto` or your images will not scale properly.

Comment: height: initial; for IE

Answer (score 6):

I'm using this technique to keep the logo as responsive for mobile devices as a simple way. The logo will resize automatically.

**HTML**

```
<div id="logo_wrapper">
  <a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">
    <img src="http://example.com/image.jpg" border="0" alt="logo" />
  </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#logo_wrapper img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

### I use this all the time

You can customize the `img` class and the `max-width` property:

```
img{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 800px;
}
```

`max-width` is important. Otherwise your image will scale too much for the desktop. There isn't any need to put in the `height` property, because by default it is auto mode.

Comment: this helped me solve markdown image responsive (redcarpet), thank you.

Answer (score 5):

If you are constrained to using an `<img>` tag:

I've found it much easier to set a `<div>` *or any other element of your choice* with a `background-image`, `width: 100%` and `background-size: 100%`.

This isn't the *end all be all* to responsive images, but it's a start. Also, try messing around with `background-size: cover` and maybe some positioning with `background-position: center`.

**CSS:**

```
.image-container{
  height: 100%; /* It doesn't have to be '%'. It can also use 'px'. */
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;

  background-image: url(../img/exampleImage.jpg);
  background-position: top center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

**HMTL:**

```
<div class="image-container"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

To make an image responsive use the following:

**CSS**

```
.responsive-image {
        width: 950px;//Any width you want to set the image to.
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<img class="responsive-image" src="IMAGE URL">
```

Answer (score 2):

Set height or the width of the image to be %100.

There is more in Stack Overflow question *[How do I auto-resize an image to fit a 'div' container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029422/image-auto-resize-to-fit-div-container)*.

Comment: What if I set it to 50%, does that mean it'll be half of the original size when scaled down?

Comment: 100% makes  it fit the container. so when you resize the page, the container gets resized, therefore the img gets resized.

Comment: Actually your the image auto resize link you sent explained it well.

Answer (score 1):

Images should be set like this

```
img { max-width: 100%; }
```

Comment: Why set both the `width` and `max-width`?

Comment: Maybe setting the width and max-width to 100% is redundant, but I've used this and it works, I've changed the answer accordingly. If the image is not set at the correct size for the element, than setting `width:  100%` will break the layout. Setting `max-width: 100%` works.

Answer (score 1):

Use Bootstrap to have a hustle free with your images
as shown. Use class img-responsive and you are done:

```
<img src="cinqueterre.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Cinque Terre" width="304" height="236">
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding CSS to make the image responsive, adding different resolution images w.r.t. different screen resolution would make the application more efficient.

Mobile browsers don't need to have the same high resolution image that the desktop browsers need.

Using SASS it's easy to use different versions of the image for different resolutions using a media query.