# Laying out icons in responsive way

Tags: css, responsive-design

I want to lay out 40x40px image icons serially which should reduce size automatically when the browser size is reduced.

After using this technique: [Make an image responsive - simplest way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458650/make-an-image-responsive-simplest-way) each image is spanning full window width (around 1144px) instead.

**How should I correct this?**

I've used the following code

```
 <div id="customtoolbar">
    <div class="topbar">
      <div class="icons">

        <a href="http://wsris:9191/" class="icon icon-papercut"><img src="sites/default/files/newicons/papercut.png" border="0" style="width:100%"></a>
        <a href="https://www.google.com/calendar" class="icon icon-cyberoam"><img src="sites/default/files/newicons/calendar.png" border="0" style="width:100%"></a>
        <a href="https://docs.google.com/" class="icon icon-drive"><img src="sites/default/files/newicons/drive.png" border="0" style="width:100%"></a>
        <a href="https://mail.google.com/" class="icon icon-gmail"><img src="sites/default/files/newicons/gmail.png" border="0" style="width:100%"></a>
        <a href="http://mycompanyschool.in/" class="icon icon-calendar"><img src="sites/default/files/newicons/calendar.png" border="0" style="width:100%"></a>
        <a href="https://classroom.google.com/u/0/welcome?emr=0" class="icon icon-classroom"><img src="sites/default/files/newicons/classroom.png" border="0" style="width:100%"></a>

    </div>
```

Comment: use `max-width:40px;`?

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer or are you happy with the solution you provided?

Comment: @apaul34208 Yes I'm looking for the right answer which should be ideal one. I mentioned what I tried from my mind.

Comment: Is there anything that is specifically less than ideal with your solution that needs to be improved?

Comment: @apaul34208  simply I want to know the best way to lay this out in adaptive way. I'm not good in CSS. What is ideal should be told by experts like you.

Answer (score 3):

Oh I made it by using "width:5%" or 6% for img tag whatever make icons look ok. Now they are responsive:

```
img{
width:5%;
height:auto;
max-width:40px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can you media queries and set the size for each resolution you want:

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {
    img{
        width:32px;
        height:32px;
    }

}

@media (min-width: 501px) {
    img{
        width:40px;
        height:40px;
    }

}
```

Here's a link about media queries at mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alexfqc/0uft975k/

You can you background-image:

HTML code:

```
<div id="penguin"></div>
```

CSS code:

```
#penguin{
    background: url('http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/penguin_clip_art_7050.jpg') no-repeat;
    width:408px;
    height:425px;
    background-size: 75%;
}
```

jsfiddle code: http://jsfiddle.net/alexfqc/ozh0qzpc/

Answer (score 1):

**Try below CSS :**

```
img {
    width:100%;
    max-width:40px;
    height:auto;
}
```

If you use css width:100%, it will set img width to available browser width. Use max-width with it.

Comment: This will keep images 40px wide on all screens unless the screen is less than 40px wide.

Answer (score 1):

**An excessively over-the-top solution**

1. I suggest that you use CSS sprites i.e. instead of creating half a dozen icons, just create one image that contains the required icons.
2. CSS sprites can be used as background image and made responsive using `background-size: cover`.
3. Use fixed-aspect-ratio-via-padding technique so that your icons expand/shrink proportionally according to screen size.
4. Throw some text labels inside the links so that search engines can read them.

```css
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16%;                    /* 100% / 6, subtract some room for whitespace */
  max-width: 40px;               /* maximum 40px wide */
  text-indent: -999px;           /* this hides the text labels */
  background-size: cover;        /* crop-fill the icon with background image */
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPkRn.png);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000000;
}
.icon:after {
  content: "";                   /* this is the fixed aspect ratio trick */
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 100%;
  width: 1px;
  vertical-align: bottom;        /* this elimiates bottom whitespace */
}
.icon.icon-papercut {
  background-position: 0 0;      /* align background's top-left */
}
.icon.icon-cyberoam {
  background-position: 0 20%;    /* 6 icons on sprite -> 0, 20%, 40%, ..., 100% */
}
.icon.icon-drive {
  background-position: 0 40%;
}
.icon.icon-gmail {
  background-position: 0 60%;
}
.icon.icon-calendar {
  background-position: 0 80%;
}
.icon.icon-classroom {
  background-position: 0 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="icons">
  <a href="#" class="icon icon-papercut">Papercut</a>
  <a href="#" class="icon icon-cyberoam">Cyberoam</a>
  <a href="#" class="icon icon-drive">Drive</a>
  <a href="#" class="icon icon-gmail">GMail</a>
  <a href="#" class="icon icon-calendar">Calendar</a>
  <a href="#" class="icon icon-classroom">Classroom</a>
</div>
```

This is the image used in the example:

[image: CSS sprite for the six icons]