# Place image in html using css

Tags: html, css

I have an image(Logo). This logo is bit larger than my required size. Is it possible to place this image in a specified size using css. The screen should be responsive so X and Y coordinates have to specified in percentage. Can this be done?

Comment: you should read this article before posting question { http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask }

Comment: Still wondering how your code might look! [Create Demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: You can specify either `width` or `height` in your css, in px or %, whatever you like. As long as you only specify one of them, the other will be automatically calculated by the browser to keep the aspect ratio.

Comment: @divy39931 how to share the code in fiddle here?

Comment: is it possible to specify the image size? What is the code to achieve this in css

Comment: post your code here. so that we can see what you really mean.

Answer (score 1):

Set the image

```
img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

It will occupied the whole container size.
The height will be set automatically to save the original width/height ratio.

Visit this question: [Make an image responsive - simplest way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458650/make-an-image-responsive-simplest-way)