# Make images responsive using css with WP reponsive theme

Tags: css

Ok, I'm using a responsive WP Theme and just discovered my images are not responsive. I understand why but my limited CSS is hindering me big time.

All the images have fixed width and heights.  I want all images to be responsive so can I not simply override all img tags with new CSS to make them responsive? Do I need a widget to do this?

I've been trying simple CSS entries like

I can directly affect the size of each image using something similar to above but no matter what combination of width, height, max-height and %'s I use the images stay a fixed size and distort the page when mobile.

Comment: img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width:100%;
}

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make an image responsive - simplest way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458650/make-an-image-responsive-simplest-way)

Comment: try either `img{display:block; width:auto; max-width:100%;}` or `img{display:block; width:auto !important; max-width:100% !important;}`.