# Can I make an image responsive using only Html tags without any CSS?

Tags: html, responsive-design

I'm making a strictly html5 page for class and we're not allowed to use CSS yet. Is there  way to make an image responsive with plain html tags?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make an image responsive - simplest way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458650/make-an-image-responsive-simplest-way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can set the width="N%" and the image will resize based on the width of the browser window. So 100% will fill the screen, 50% will fill half, etc.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm :)