# Psd to html image responsive

Tags: html, responsive, psd

I have a jpg photo that size is 1920 px width but I want to responsive this width.

**HTML**

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>image</title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   </head>
   <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
      <!-- Save for Web Slices (image.jpg) --> 
      <table id="Table_01" style="width:50%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
         <tr>
            <td colspan="17"> <img src="images/image_01.jpg" width="1920" height="29" alt=""></td>
            <td> 
         </tr>
         <tr> <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="45" alt=""></td> </tr>
      </table>
      <!-- End Save for Web Slices --> 
   </body>
</html>
```

How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: Please post your code **in the question itself** so that we can help you.

Comment: I can't give this code here it always show error when i paste my code in my question .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make an image responsive - simplest way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458650/make-an-image-responsive-simplest-way)

Answer (score 3):

You could use % to make the image responsive instead of px.

For eg,u can use 50% width to make the image half the size of the page.
(width=50% ,instead of width=___px) 
`<img src="source.jpeg" width="50%" height="75%">`

Comment: Which section i add width 50% ?

Comment: <html>
<head>
<title>image</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="width:50%;">
<!-- Save for Web Slices (image.jpg) -->
<div id="ima">
<table id="Table_01" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
 <tr  >
  <td colspan="17">
   <img src="images/image_01.jpg" width="1920" height="29" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="29" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <

Comment: change width="1920" to width="50%"

Comment: can you come skype ?

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution is to change the width in the css file.

`class-name-of-image.img{
width=50%;
height=75%;
}`