# How can I make my background image 'img-responsive'?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how can I make my background image using bootstrap 'img-responsive'? The background image is with in `hero`div

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <html lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Liam Docherty Digital Portfolio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .navbar.navbar-default {
      background-color: #4D5061;
      height: 10vh;
      z-index: 100;
    }
    
    .navbar.navbar-default ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      text-align: right;
    }
    
    .navbar.navbar-default ul li {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-menu li {
      text-align: center
    }
    
    .dropdown .dropdown-menu {
      background-color: #4D5061;
    }
    
    .dropdown .dropdown-menu a {
      color: white;
    }
    
    .navbar.navbar-default ul li a {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 3.5vh 8px 4px;
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 14pt;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    }
    
    .navbar.navbar-default ul li:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      right: 50%;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 50%;
      height: 3px;
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      border-radius: 9px;
      transition: all .2s;
    }
    
    .navbar.navbar-default ul li a:hover {
      color: white;
    }
    
    .nav.navbar-nav,
    .nav.navbar-nav>li {
      float: none;
    }
    
    .navbar.navbar-default ul li:hover:after {
      right: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
    
    .nav-title {
      font-size: 14pt;
      margin: 0;
      top: 35px;
      left: 50px;
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    }
    
    .navbar.navbar-default ul.dropdown-menu li,
    .navbar.navbar-default ul.dropdown-menu li a {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
    }
    
    #logo {
      padding-top: 2vh;
      padding-left: 20px;
      float: left;
    }
    
    .hero {
      background-image: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/48727/pexels-photo-48727.jpeg");
      background-attachment: fixed;
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    section {
      position: relative;
      height: 95vh;
    }
    
    .section1 {
      height: 100vh;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
    }
    
    .section2 {
      background-color: #11B5E4;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
    }
    
    .section3 {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
    }
    
    .fa-angle-down {
      color: #4D5061;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0px;
    }
    
    .fa-angle-up {
      color: #4D5061;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0px;
    }
    
    .footer {
      height: 6vh;
      background-color: #4D5061;
      padding: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
    
    .footertext {
      font-size: 14pt;
      color: white;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .profile.box {
      bottom: 0;
      height: 50%;
      left: 0;
      margin: auto;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 50%;
    }
    
    .shape {
      border-radius: 25px;
      background: #4D5061;
      content: url(http://i1126.photobucket.com/albums/l611/ldocherty1/IMG_0730_zpsiz4dqc47.jpg);
      color: white;
      height: 250px;
      margin: auto;
      padding: 3px;
      width: 250px;
    }
    
    .shape2 {
      background: linear-gradient(35deg, #4D5061, #4D5061);
      border-radius: 85px;
      color: white;
      height: 40px;
      margin: 1% auto;
      opacity: 0.9;
      padding: 0px;
      width: 250px;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt="Your Brand Name"></a>
        <h1 class="nav-title">Liam Docherty's Digital Portfolio</h1>
      </div>
      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">About Me <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#section3">Contact</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Units <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
              </li>

              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
              </li>

              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Clients</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#contact-me">Contact Me</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>


  <section id="section1" class="section1">
    <div class="hero">
      <div class="profile box">
        <div class="shape"></div>
        <div class="shape2">
          <p>kjjjjjjjjjkjjjkkjkj</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>





    <a href="#section2"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>

  </section>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be really helpful to create a jsFiddle or CodePen with a stripped down targeted example like this next time: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/c5h2hczs/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `background-size: cover`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

> **cover** - A keyword that is the inverse of contain. Scales the image as large as possible and maintains image aspect ratio (image doesn't get squished). The image "covers" the entire width or height of the container. When the image and container have different dimensions, the image is clipped either left/right or top/bottom.

Alternatively you might try `contain` depending on your desired behavior, but from the looks of your portfolio, `cover` is what you want

> **contain**: A keyword that scales the image as large as possible and maintains image aspect ratio (image doesn't get squished). Image is letterboxed within the container. When the image and container have different dimensions, the empty areas (either top/bottom of left/right) are filled with the background-color.

* edit - also added `background-position: center center; background-repeat: no-repeat;` in the shorthand `background` property for `.hero` since from the looks of your portfolio, you want those.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <html lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Liam Docherty Digital Portfolio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .navbar.navbar-default {
      background-color: #4D5061;
      height: 10vh;
      z-index: 100;
    }
    
    .navbar.navbar-default ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      text-align: right;
    }
    
    .navbar.navbar-default ul li {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-menu li {
      text-align: center
    }
    
    .dropdown .dropdown-menu {
      background-color: #4D5061;
    }
    
    .dropdown .dropdown-menu a {
      color: white;
    }
    
    .navbar.navbar-default ul li a {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 3.5vh 8px 4px;
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 14pt;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    }
    
    .navbar.navbar-default ul li:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      right: 50%;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 50%;
      height: 3px;
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      border-radius: 9px;
      transition: all .2s;
    }
    
    .navbar.navbar-default ul li a:hover {
      color: white;
    }
    
    .nav.navbar-nav,
    .nav.navbar-nav>li {
      float: none;
    }
    
    .navbar.navbar-default ul li:hover:after {
      right: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
    
    .nav-title {
      font-size: 14pt;
      margin: 0;
      top: 35px;
      left: 50px;
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    }
    
    .navbar.navbar-default ul.dropdown-menu li,
    .navbar.navbar-default ul.dropdown-menu li a {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
    }
    
    #logo {
      padding-top: 2vh;
      padding-left: 20px;
      float: left;
    }
    
    .hero {
      background: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/48727/pexels-photo-48727.jpeg") center center no-repeat;;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      position: relative;
      background-size: cover;
      text-align: center;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    section {
      position: relative;
      height: 95vh;
    }
    
    .section1 {
      height: 100vh;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
    }
    
    .section2 {
      background-color: #11B5E4;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
    }
    
    .section3 {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
    }
    
    .fa-angle-down {
      color: #4D5061;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0px;
    }
    
    .fa-angle-up {
      color: #4D5061;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0px;
    }
    
    .footer {
      height: 6vh;
      background-color: #4D5061;
      padding: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
    
    .footertext {
      font-size: 14pt;
      color: white;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .profile.box {
      bottom: 0;
      height: 50%;
      left: 0;
      margin: auto;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 50%;
    }
    
    .shape {
      border-radius: 25px;
      background: #4D5061;
      content: url(http://i1126.photobucket.com/albums/l611/ldocherty1/IMG_0730_zpsiz4dqc47.jpg);
      color: white;
      height: 250px;
      margin: auto;
      padding: 3px;
      width: 250px;
    }
    
    .shape2 {
      background: linear-gradient(35deg, #4D5061, #4D5061);
      border-radius: 85px;
      color: white;
      height: 40px;
      margin: 1% auto;
      opacity: 0.9;
      padding: 0px;
      width: 250px;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt="Your Brand Name"></a>
        <h1 class="nav-title">Liam Docherty's Digital Portfolio</h1>
      </div>
      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">About Me <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#section3">Contact</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Units <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
              </li>

              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
              </li>

              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Clients</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#contact-me">Contact Me</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>


  <section id="section1" class="section1">
    <div class="hero">
      <div class="profile box">
        <div class="shape"></div>
        <div class="shape2">
          <p>kjjjjjjjjjkjjjkkjkj</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>





    <a href="#section2"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>

  </section>
</html>
```

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw that doesn't behave the same way. The image will repeat or create blank gaps at the top/bottom if OP's browser is portrait since the image is landscape.

Comment: You also have to include `background-position: center` or else smaller sizes will not be responsive.

Comment: @sequential good call but it's still responsive in a small screen, as in it scales. what value they want to use with `background-position` depends on what part of the image they want visible. but agreed that they probably want center, i'll add that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
<div>
    <img src="IMAGE LINK" style='width:100%;' border="0" alt="Null">
</div>
```

Source: [Make an image responsive - simplest way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458650/make-an-image-responsive-simplest-way)

Answer (score 0):

I personally use Jquery's Backstretch. The code is responsive and easy to plug in by using:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And then adding the style/image to a .css doc like so:

```
<style>
.content-wrapper {
    /* This image will be displayed fullscreen */

    background: url('http://site.rockbottomgolf.com/blog_images/Hole%2012%20-%20Imgur.jpg') no-repeat center fixed;

    scroll-x /* Ensure the html element always takes up the full height of the browser window */ min-height: 100%;
    /* The Magic */
    background-size: cover;
}
</style>
```

EDIT!! - I posted a link to Jquery but not the actual responsive backstretch plugin. Note you must keep the required script above and then add backstretch following it since it is a dependency. 
[Download The Backstretch Plugin Here](http://www.jquery-backstretch.com)

You would then add the script as follows:

```
<script src="example.com/relative-Path/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the assistance. Now I have added this code you recommended and it works, can I delete my <hero> div of the original image or is it still relevant?

Comment: Absolutely, just delete it as it is no longer needed.