# Resizing an image with white-space

Tags: html, css

I have three images inline - each taken a width of 33%. As you resize the window all divs including the images readjust perfectly, however rather than resize the full image, all images are resized but continually see less of the images.

I would like the sizing to act how it currently is, without losing complete view of the full image.

```
<div class = "main> 
    <div class = "image">
         <img src = "imgpathway">
    </div>

   <div class = "image">
             <img src = "imgpathway">
        </div>

    <div class = "image">
             <img src = "imgpathway">
        </div>
    </div


.main {
      white-space:nowrap;
}

.image{
    white-space:normal;
}
```

Comment: is the syntax issue you have here (not closing the main class) only here or also in your code?

Comment: Also, with the code provided the images are not inline, as you can see here: https://codepen.io/nickimola/pen/MoPLJK - can you paste more code, or, even better, adjust this pen with more of your code please?

Comment: add `.image img { max-width: 100%; }`

Comment: perfect @MichaelCoker, thank you very much :) If you want to post this as an answer and I can accept it for you if you'd like.

Comment: @James cool you're welcome. Nah, this question is asked all the time. I can either flag it as a duplicate or you can remove it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458650/make-an-image-responsive-simplest-way