# I am trying to create grid like image given below

Tags: html, css

How can i add patch to image in grid. and how can I change size of grid images. I am making it mobile friendly. It should be mobile responsive.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <style>
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body {
        margin: 0;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    .header {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 32px;
    }

    .row {
        display: -ms-flexbox; /* IE 10 */
        display: flex;
        -ms-flex-wrap: wrap; /* IE 10 */
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        padding: 0 4px;
    }

    /* Create two equal columns that sits next to each other */
    .column {
        -ms-flex: 50%; /* IE 10 */
        flex: 50%;
        padding: 0 8px;
    }

    .column img {
        margin-top: 7px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        border-radius: 5%;
    }

    </style>
    <body>

    <!-- Header -->
    <div class="header" id="myHeader">
      <h1>Image Grid</h1>
      <p>Click on the buttons to change the grid view.</p>
    </div>

    <!-- Photo Grid -->
    <div class="row"> 
      <div class="column">
        <img src="character.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <img src="https://d2pu2bk1b66iw6.cloudfront.net/photos/2014/08/01/6-74677-mm_babymeme3-1406927575.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <img src="character.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <img src="https://d2pu2bk1b66iw6.cloudfront.net/photos/2014/08/01/6-74677-mm_babymeme3-1406927575.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <img src="lover_name.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <img src="character.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <img src="http://www.quickmeme.com/img/66/66e01f5ecd44767a19bb8e9a0f3e97da92a660048860eef482c6c2b66871f4a1.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <img src="https://d2pu2bk1b66iw6.cloudfront.net/photos/2014/08/01/6-74677-mm_babymeme3-1406927575.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>  
    </div>

    <script>
    // Get the elements with class="column"
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("column");

    // Declare a loop variable
    var i;

    // Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
    var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
    var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("btn");
    for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
      btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
        current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
        this.className += " active";
      });
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

I am trying to create grid like image given below. I am also trying to add patch to given image.
How can i change size of each image in grid view. It should be mobile responsive to make it work with any screen.

[image: I am trying to create this type of grid]

Comment: I think it’s easier to use a Grid system like the one in Bootstrap, or any one you like, it should let you add the images in rows, and it’ll take care of the resizing upon screen change.

Comment: Please can you give me any example ?

Comment: What should the image sizes be? and what do you mean by patch?

Comment: size just little increased. patch means trending like in image.

Comment: You can use boostrap, here is the ref. for your goal - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/images/

Comment: Refer answers to this similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458650/make-an-image-responsive-simplest-way

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
<!-- Photo Grid -->
    <div class="row" style=“width:100%”> 
      <div class="column" style="width:50%">
        <img src="character.jpg" style="width:25%">
        <img src="https://d2pu2bk1b66iw6.cloudfront.net/photos/2014/08/01/6-74677-mm_babymeme3-1406927575.jpg" style="width:25%">
        <img src="character.jpg" style="width:25%">
        <img src="https://d2pu2bk1b66iw6.cloudfront.net/photos/2014/08/01/6-74677-mm_babymeme3-1406927575.jpg" style="width:25%">
      </div>
      <div class="column" style="width:50%">
        <img src="lover_name.jpg" style="width:25%">
        <img src="character.jpg" style="width:25%">
        <img src="http://www.quickmeme.com/img/66/66e01f5ecd44767a19bb8e9a0f3e97da92a660048860eef482c6c2b66871f4a1.jpg" style="width:25%">
        <img src="https://d2pu2bk1b66iw6.cloudfront.net/photos/2014/08/01/6-74677-mm_babymeme3-1406927575.jpg" style="width:25%">
      </div>  
    </div>
```

Consider editing those percentages a little if you are willing to add margins or padding.