# CSS scale down image to fit in containing div, without specifing original size

Tags: html, css, scaling

I want to have a website where I can upload images of different sizes to be displayed in a jquery slider.
I can't seem to fit (scaling down) the image in a containing div. Here's how I'm intending to do it

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org    /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Imtest.css"/>
</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper"> 

<div id="im"><img src="Images/Scarpa2_1.jpg" /></div>

</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS

```
#wrapper {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 2px black solid;
    margin: auto;
}

#im {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

I've tried to set the max-width of my image to 100% in CSS. But that doens't work.

Comment: try #im img{ display:block; height:100%; width:100%;} but small images may looks bad..!

Comment: Strangely that you say that setting `max-width` of the image to 100% doesn't help. [It works perfectly](http://jsfiddle.net/h6732/).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image auto resize to fit div container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029422/image-auto-resize-to-fit-div-container)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can use a [background image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) to accomplish this;

From MDN - [Background Size: Contain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size):

> This keyword specifies that the background image should be scaled to be as large as possible while ensuring both its dimensions are less than or equal to the corresponding dimensions of the background positioning area.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcl64/tus3d/1/)

CSS:

```
#im {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-image: url("path/to/img");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="im">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Problem: background-image will not be SEO friendly.

Answer (score 19):

This is an old question I know, but this is in the top five for several related Google searches. Here's the CSS-only solution without changing the images to background images:

```
width: auto;
height: auto;
max-width: MaxSize;
max-height: MaxSize;
```

"MaxSize" is a placeholder for whatever `max-width` and `max-height` you want to use, in pixels or percentage. `auto` will increase (or decrease) the width and height to occupy the space you specify with MaxSize. It will override any defaults for images you or the viewer's browser might have for images. I've found it's especially important on Android's Firefox. Pixels or percentages work for max size. With both the height and width set to `auto`, the aspect ratio of the original image will be retained.

If you want to fill the space entirely and don't mind the image being larger than its original size, change the two `max-width`s to `min-width: 100%` - this will make them completely occupy their space and maintain aspect ratio. You can see an example of this with a Twitter profile's background image.

Comment: What's the support like for `MaxSize`?

Comment: That's just a placeholder for whatever max-width and max-height you want to use, in pixels or percentage (providing a width and height is set on the parent.)

Comment: Care to expand what's not working in particular? It's hard to troubleshoot "that doesn't work" :)

Comment: @WoodyPayne Where do you put these lines? Inside a `div` object or do you have to access the `custom.css` file?

Comment: Please add that you set this to the `img` itself, not to its container.

Answer (score 8):

if you want both width and the height you can try

```
 background-size: cover !important;
```

but this wont distort the image but fill the div.

Answer (score 5):

I believe this is the best way of doing it, I've tried it and it works very well.

```
#img {
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

[This is where I found it](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/). Good luck!

Comment: Currently poor browser support. Otherwise this would be the best solution.

Answer (score 3):

It's very simple. Just Set width of img to 100%

Comment: This will not work for images with aspect ratio less than 1.

Comment: This also scales up the images if the div container is larger than the image

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will answer the age old problem *(Without using CSS **background** property)*

**Html**

```
<div class="card-cont">
 <img src="demo.png" />
</div>
```

**Css**

```
.card-cont{
  width:100%;
  height:150px;
}

.card-cont img{
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using this, both smaller and large images:

```
.product p.image {
text-align: center;
width: 220px;
height: 160px;
overflow: hidden;
}
.product p.image img{
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have met the same issue and fixed using the following CSS.
Hope this would help you.

```
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
width: max-content;
height: max-content;
```

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
.image {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: max-content;
  height: max-content;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <img class='image' alt='' src="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/95250818?v=4"></img>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I use:

object-fit: cover;
-o-object-fit: cover;

to place images in a container with a fixed height and width, this also works great for my sliders. It will however cut of parts of the image depending on it's.

Comment: Have no idea why it had been voted down. It's the option ever!

Answer (score 0):

In a webpage where I wanted a in image to scale with browser size change and remain at the top, next to a fixed div, all I had to do was use a single CSS line: `overflow:hidden;` and it did the trick. The image scales perfectly.

What is especially nice is that this is pure css and will work even if Javascript is turned off.

**CSS:**

```
#ImageContainerDiv {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="ImageContainerDiv">
  <a href="URL goes here" target="_blank">
    <img src="MapName.png" alt="Click to load map" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: For large images, it will cut / hide the extra instead of shrink.

Answer (score 0):

Several of these things did not work for me... however, this did. Might help someone else in the future. Here is the CSS:

```
    .img-area {
     display: block;
     padding: 0px 0 0 0px;
     text-indent: 0;
     width: 100%;
     background-size: 100% 95%;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-image: url("https://yourimage.png");

    }
```