# Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.2 image in non-fluid grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I am building a template with bootstrap 2.3.2 and I want to have images that have certain dimensions according to the grid. (I'm not using the fluid grid, however I am using the responsive features).

I expect that the image which is contained e.g. in a `span4` div would shrink accordingly even if it has a larger resolution, but instead it is shown at its real pixel size. Is there a way to shrink the image according to the div size? Or do I have to apply an explicit width in the css?

I know that in plain CSS I could achieve what I want in this way: [How do I auto-resize an image to fit a div container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029422/image-auto-resize-to-fit-div-container) but I was wondering if in Bootstrap there is a dedicated class for this.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="container">  
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="span4">
                            <img class="img-polaroid" src="public/images/h1.jpg" alt="" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="span8">
                            <img class="img-polaroid" src="public/images/h2.jpg" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are set using Bootstrap 2, then your best bet is just to do what the question you referenced says, and add a specific rule in your CSS, as the 2.x branch does not have anything specific for responsive images.

Another option to consider would be to move to Bootstrap 3, which *does* have a responsive image helper. It is as simple as adding `.img-responsive` to any image. See the 3.x docs for more details at: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-responsive-images.

Comment: Until now I didn't move to bootstrap 3 only because I'm lazy. But this might be a very good reason to do so, thank you for the hint buddy.

Comment: Although, having a look at the link you gave me, it looks like adding this class to bootstrap 2 is as easy as: `.img-responsive{max-width: 100%; height: auto;}`

Comment: Yeah, I was going to suggest that you could just do that if you wanted to stay with v2 but be ready for a future migration to v3. You could also just do `img {max-width: 100%; height: auto;}` and not worry about classes if you knew that all of your images would need to be responsive.