# if an image isnt a background how do i make it fit it's container

Tags: html, image, css

Iv found an image slider the url is below. the image has to be a certain height + width as 
specified in the css ..  but my images are to big is there a way to make the images "strech"
because im not going to resize 100+ images .. these are not set as background images.

[Here is the page](http://www.menucool.com/slider/javascript-image-slider-demo1)
hopefully this can help any one else who has problem's with image slider's size..

i would write a jsfiddle but there is to much code to include sorry for the inconvenience

** **Things iv tryed** **

```
img{height:100%;width:100%;}
img{max-height:100%;max-width:100%}
```

aswell as adding the  `style=""`  in the img tag

Comment: Have you defined a width and a height to the parent container of the img tag?

Comment: check this stackoverflow [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029422/image-auto-resize-to-fit-div-container)

Comment: @ShreshttBhatt the answer to that question didnt work i clarified that in my post!

Comment: Have you tried `img{display:inline-block;position:relative;width:100%}`

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore post as answer please ill accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to have an image as `inline-block` and then give it `width:100%`

```
img{display:inline-block;position:relative;width:100%}
```