# Fit divs vertically on a parent div with fixed height and width

Tags: css, html

I have a layout wherein the container has a `fixed height and width of 640px x 480px`. Inside this container are 3 divs, `top`, `mid` and `bot`. I want this 3 divs to fit inside the container provided that they will not overflow the container. The `top` and `bot` div doesn't have fixed height while the `mid` should fit the space between and push top and bot.

What I've already tried was like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="top">
    </div>
    <div class="mid">
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bf/Chestnut-breasted_Malkoha2.jpg/593px-Chestnut-breasted_Malkoha2.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="bot">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.main {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 640px;
    height: 480px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #000;
    position: relative;
}
.top {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    background: #eee;

}
.mid {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    background: #333;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
.bot {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/J6QTg/10/)

Now my problem is the mid push the bot outside the container. How can i make them fit inside the container **without using overflow: hidden**? Thanks in advance.

`NOTE :` [the image should fit inside the `mid` container.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029422/image-auto-resize-to-fit-div-container)

**UPDATE** `top` and `bot` div can contain paragraphs so it's not fixed height.

Comment: You can use the `calc()` like this http://jsfiddle.net/J6QTg/2/ although it's not supported by some really old browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/J6QTg/8/

```
.main {
    padding: 50px 0px;
    width: 640px;
    height: 480px;
    display: block;
    background: #000;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.top {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    background: #eee;
    position: absolute;
    top : 0;
    left : 0;
}
.mid {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    background: #333;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
.bot {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    background: #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    bottom : 0;
    left : 0;
}
```

**Update:**

It is also possible to use tables, to have more flexible boxes.

http://jsfiddle.net/jslayer/U3EaZ/

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="h"> Hello<br/>Cruel<br/>World </div>
    <div class="m">
        <img src="http://goo.gl/a1smCR" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="b"> Omg </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
    display: table;
    width: 640px;
    height: 480px;
    background: red;
}

.h, .m, .b {
    display: table-row;
}

.h {
    background: yellow;
    height: 0;
}

.m {
    background: green;
}

.m img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}

.b {
    background: blue;
    height: 0;
}
```

Comment: what if my `top` div is not fixed in height. for example i have 10 sentences? padding top will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I would use JavaScript/JQuery: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/J6QTg/4/)

I've used JQuery for simplicity, but it can probably be done with just JavaScript...

```
var totalheight = eval($('.main').height() - $('.top').outerHeight(true) - $('.bot').outerHeight(true))
$('.mid').outerHeight(totalheight);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the container has a fixed height and width, then you can set the height to 79.25% like this:

```
.mid {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 79.25%;
    display: block;
    background: #333;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/J6QTg/9/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the height of mid based on the container.

```
.mid {
    width: 100%;
    height: 383px;
    display: block;
    background: #333;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/J6QTg/7/)

Comment: sorry but i cannot only rely on fixed height value