# Fire function after each image is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I am trying to fill a div with images and size the images to fit just right in their place.  The problem is that when the image is not loaded, the dimensions x , y cannot be sampled from the  element.  This is what I am trying to do after looking up some examples on stack overflow.  It does not work...

```
    $.each(data.data.children, function(i,item){
        // Some images come in with a busted link. Hence the IF statement...
        if (item.data.url.indexOf(".jpg")>0){
            var imgTitle = item.data.title;
            imgTitle = imgTitle;
            $('<div id="c'+i+'"></div>').attr("class", "imgDiv").appendTo("#photos");
            $("<img/>").attr("src", item.data.url).attr("id", "pic"+i).attr("class", "pics").appendTo("#c"+i);
                .load(function(){
                    $(this).fadein("slow");
                    if (iWidth>iHeight){
                        $('#pic'+i).width(270);
                        $('#pic'+i).height(parseInt(270-imgTitle.length/3));
                    }
                });

            $("<p>"+imgTitle+"</p>").attr("id", "p"+i).appendTo("#c"+i);  
            $("<img/>").attr("src", "images/RedX2.png").attr("class", "xit").appendTo("#c"+i);

            var mImg = $('#pic'+i)[0];
        }
    });
```

Alternatively, is there a way to do proportional fitting of an image inside the padding space proportionally?

TIA

DK

[image]

Comment: Can you get some HTML or example what you you want to achieve?

Comment: Do you know the aspect of all the images or does it vary?

Comment: The images are all different sizes.  They may be 1920x1080 or they can be 300x500...  any shape imaginable...

Comment: @Lesha I added a picture for you to see it...

Comment: Vertical images do not need to be adjusted  They drop in perfectly

Comment: I think you looking for `margin-auto` http://jsbin.com/puwoyi/1/

Comment: margin-auto is used for centering, I think  ...  max-height and max-width did it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might not need any javascript at all.  See this post for a way to use CSS to have the image automatically size to the div that contains it.

[How do I auto-resize an image to fit a div container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029422/image-auto-resize-to-fit-div-container)

Comment: don't use max-height.

Comment: Actually using both max-height and max-width together and removing height property did it.

Comment: @HeadCode It did work.  My mistake.  I had height set to 70%  and that was messing things up...  Thank you, you gave me the best solution...