# Max-height works sometimes, but not always

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a responsive website. My images exist in a div window I called "preview" and they are not supposed to exceed the height of the window. It seems to be working for certain images, and I can't figure out why it won't work for all of them.

Probably not necessary, but this is my code for the div.

```
.preview {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Here's an example of an image that's working.

```
<img class="preview" src="assets/works/design/posters/spring2016.jpg">
```

This one isn't working. It is taller than the div height.

```
<img class="preview" src="assets/works/reindeer.jpg">
```

Here's my site: alexjberger.com

Does anyone have any insight? I appreciate it.

Comment: Went to your site and could not figure out what you were trying to say, but then I finally got it.  The div itself never goes greater than 100%.  It's the images that do.  I'd recommend adding this to your css:

`.preview img { max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%}`

Comment: Looks like you got an answer, just wanted to say you're sketchbook stuff is great, really unique.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS max-height not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520710/css-max-height-not-working) or [max-height: x% doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27992881/max-height-x-doesnt-work-on-chrome)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the images parent `p` a height as well to make it work.

*For an element to respect a height given in percent, its parent also must have a height, and if that as well is given in percent, the next parent etc. One often ends up with this rule `html, body { margin: 0; height: 100%; }`*

Comment: What height can I make it without using pixels?

Comment: @AlexBerger Set `height: 100%;` to the `p` and it will work fine

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks so much.