# Removing white space under nested img when resizing without squeezing image

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout, fluid-images

I'm making a basic header using divs and a nested img in a fluid layout. I'm a bit rusty on this and i can't for the love of me figure out how to ensure that the image nested in the div scales without scaling to the point where it becomes smaller its parent div.

[EDIT: Updated the codepen link showing how using min-height won't work as it squeezes the image](http://codepen.io/knode/pen/JYNrwZ)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item half">
    <p>
      Some text
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item half">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/hd1080" class="full-width">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1920px;
}

.item{
    height: 300px;
    float:left;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: gray;
}

.half{
    width: 50%
}

.full-width{
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

And for good measure a quick illustration of what is happening:
[image]

And an illustration of what i want to happen:

Edit: Note that the image here is *not* being squeezed, which is what happens if you set the image to have a min-height equal to its parent div. But rather the overflow is hidden. You can also see that i do not mind the images being cropped.
[image]

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Could you get the effect you want by making the image of the right div a tiled background?

Comment: Hi @protonfish, no unfortunately. I want to avoid using background-image and keep the image as a nested img.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find the solution i wanted in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30794589/1211280) thread. The function i was looking for was `object-fit`.

I've used the following solution:

```
img{
    min-height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Edit: quickly found out that this property is only properly supported by Firefox, Chrome and Opera. Use [this polyfill](https://github.com/anselmh/object-fit) to fix this on Safari and IE.

Answer (score 2):

You can add min-height equal to the div.item height to your image CSS

```
img {
    max-width:100%;
    min-height:300px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry @lddz, i have to remove this as the answer, as the img is now being squeezed. I will update the question with this info.