# JS/jQuery fit all images inside div (without whitespace)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have a `div` call it `#container`,
Inside this `#container` I have `n` amount of `img` tags call it `images`
`n` can be 2, 10, 40 and so on.
I am wondering how I can fit `n` amount of `images` inside a `#container` to close all white spaces `stretch` the images. Quality doesn't matter
This is what I tried until now:

```
var amount = $("#container > img").length;
var amount_w = amount*200; //200 width of 1 image 
var amount_h = amount*130; //120 height  image 
var refH = $("#container").height();
var refW = $("#container").width();

var refRatio = refW/refH;
$("#container img").each(function(){
     $(this).height((amount_h-130)-refH);
     $(this).width((amount_w-230)-refW);
});
```

Comment: Do you want them to be in a row?

Comment: This might help: [Image auto resize to fit div container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029422/image-auto-resize-to-fit-div-container?rq=1)

Comment: what is the 200 and 130 and 230 at the bottom?

Comment: @juallom no whatever so they fit the whole `#container`
@Pete img size from beging

Comment: @Roberto this is for 1 Image, but I have `n` number of images

Comment: @Froxz - How about a library like 
[Masonry - Cascading grid layout library](http://masonry.desandro.com/) ? "works by placing elements in optimal position based on available vertical space..."

Comment: @Roberto I Tried them but they dont fill the whole container< they still leave some space. And if you have less than 2-3 elements also dont fill. I need just some sort of formula< on how can I calculate the width and height of `images`

Comment: what's the behaviour of your `#container`? Does it also wrap/resize depending on the amount of images?

Comment: @DigitalDouble Nope container resizes only on screen resize, so it fit the screen.

Comment: One more question, when you say quality doesn't matter does that mean the images can stretch out of the original aspect ratio?

Comment: @DigitalDouble yes, because with aspect ratio is mathematically imposible as I think!

Comment: Why not you use them as `background-image` and use `background-size: contain` property? I can make a fiddle for you if that helps

Comment: That could probably work with combination with flex-box

Comment: @Froxz See if this helps? http://jsfiddle.net/amigoo/b06owp2c/1/

Comment: @FaisalAshfaq unfortunately no(((

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, **it IS possible to achieve what you need even while maintaining the aspect ratio of the images** - however the row height will be calculated, but it is not a trivial task (well, at least not as trivial as a single line formula).

There is a jQuery plugin called **[jPictura](https://github.com/anmarcek/jpictura)** which I have developed. I believe the plugin does exactly what you need.

**[Here is a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n2zcxp6u/4/).**

You can find the plugin source codes and documentation on [GitHub](https://github.com/anmarcek/jpictura).

Simple example how to use the plugin:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#my-gallery').jpictura({
        layout: { itemSpacing: 0, justifyLastRow: true, idealRowHeight: 200}
    });
});
```

- itemSpacing - amount of space between the images in pixels
- justifyLastRow - if true, the images in last row will be stretched to take the full width of the row
- idealRowHeight - The desired height of the rows in pixels. The plugin will do its best to arrange the items so the row heights are as close as possible to this value.
- **there are a lot more options documented on GitHub**

Beside the JS stuff that calculates the correct widths and heights of the images, there is one more thing to be considered regarding the blank space between images. Images are by default inline-blocks which means they behave like words and words do have some white space inbetween, right? Make them `display: block; float: left;` or use the flex box layout to get rid of the blank space. The plugin uses `float: left;` by default.

Comment: Thank you but before to apply this I need to resize them based on container width and height. So they fit container without white space left!

Comment: @Froxz, Yeah, I got the point now - it is not a trivial task if you want to make it properly - see [this link](http://www.domjudov.sk/sk/fotogaleria/album/?idAlbum=86&back=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domjudov.sk%2Fsk%2Ffotogaleria%2F). I made a jQuery plugin for a gallery which looks like this (the page utilizes my plugin). The white space is configurable, images fit perfectly in row and their width/height ratio is persisted. I can share details in the evening - do not have enough time to describe it at the moment. Just please reply if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: will take a look, but as I see at the bottom you still have 2 missing pictures.

Comment: @Froxz, good remark however that is intended behavior - I wanted the last line to be like that - you can change it so all lines are full stretched. Just be prepared for a math lesson ;). Or I can share the whole plugin but I have to clean it up - was developed in hurry years ago and is quite messy.

Comment: I hope you will share you code, when you have time))))

Comment: @Froxz, sorry for being late, I was quite busy yesterday - please see my updated post. I haven't had a chance to clean up and publish on Github or anywhere else but in the updated answer you can find a link to jsfiddle which contains all the code you need. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you a lot will try it, seems perfect

Comment: Hey @Froxz, finally I have published a plugin. Many bug fixes and improvements were added since I posted my previous fiddle. I Hope it helps - see details in the updated answer.

Comment: thank you, but I went more simple, output only 30 images and resize them width = containerWidth/6, height = containerWidth/5

Answer (score 2):

I created something that might interest you

```
var container = $('#container');
var height = container.outerHeight();
var width = container.outerWidth();

function populate(n){
    var rem_items = n;
    var rows = Math.round(Math.sqrt(n));
    var row_items = Math.ceil(n/rows);

    for (var i=0; i<rows; i++){

        // this prevents us from generating a lonely single box in a row
        if( (rem_items%(rows-i))===0 ){
            row_items = rem_items/(rows-i);
        }

        if(rem_items<row_items){
            row_items = rem_items;
        }

        rem_items = rem_items-row_items;

        for (var j=0; j<row_items; j++){
            var img_height = height/rows;
            var img_width = width/row_items;
            var img_left = j*img_width;
            var img_top = i*img_height;
            var img = $('<div class="cell"></div>');
            img.css({
                width: img_width,
                height: img_height,
                left: img_left,
                top: img_top
            });
            container.append(img);
        }
    }
}

populate(40);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jLq4hgaa/1/

Basically, it calculates the "most balanced" distribution of the images horizontally and vertically.

It does what you're asking for in the plainest sense. It distributes images/containers inside a container evenly regardless of aspect ratio.

Comment: unfortunately didn't helped. I Will try to change a lil bit your code

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("pageload",function(){
  $('.container').addClass('stretch');
});
```

Then make a css element called "stretch" defining width:100%

Height:100% and if need be define layout, i.e relative

Comment: Will check This! Thank you