# HTML fit image to parent's parent

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to fit an image inside some divs and make it as big as possible without changing the aspect ratio. Setting max-height and max-width to 100% on both the image and its parent does not work and the image overflows (I guess because the parent does not really have a width or height so the image can not resize to it?).

[JSFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/cgj58gL0/1/)

```
<div class="block">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-9">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="placeholder" src="https://unsplash.it/900/600" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:**
I will clarify what I really want to achieve later this evening when I have time to write.

Answer (score 1):

Set the the image as background image to `.thumbnail`, and constrict it's size using `background-size` ([demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/zov7c2eg/)):

```
.thumbnail {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url("https://unsplash.it/900/600") no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the parent `div` to match its content, add `display:table;` in your "outline-block" `css` class.

[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/cgj58gL0/2/)

Similar post on stack overflow: [how-do-i-auto-resize-an-image-to-fit-a-div-container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029422/how-do-i-auto-resize-an-image-to-fit-a-div-container?rq=1)

Comment: This sets the "block"s height to the image but I want the image to fit inside "block" without overflowing.

Comment: @igortreptau I have updated the code here: [link](http://fiddle.jshell.net/cgj58gL0/3/)    (applied `css` directly on `img` tag)

Comment: I think @Ori Drori 's answer is what you are looking for!