# Enlage a small IMG to fit parent size without deforming Aspect ratio

Tags: html, css

My website contains after clicking a topic, one `img` that chances on another `img` click. the image sources themselves are not that large and can't fit a 1080 x 1920 display. If the user has a large screen or uses a zoom-out browser function, i want the `img` to enlarge, to keep the dimensions of the parent.

[Here is a Fiddle on how it **should** look like](https://jsfiddle.net/wg5pttLt/4/), altered from http://jsfiddle.net/xwrvxser/1/

The fiddle here has 100% height but that maxes out the img height and creates a stretched img element as shown in background color red, thats what im trying to avoid, No red stretched img just keep the Aspect ratio and no pixel more.
(try and resize the Fiddle window and you will see the img stretching red).
[this is what happens when the parent size changes](https://jsfiddle.net/807/wg5pttLt/6/).

[With all the `img` topics on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029422/how-do-i-auto-resize-an-image-to-fit-a-div-container) none has a answer for just a `img` that doesn't deform but maintains the parent div dimensions keeping its own Aspect ratio and doesn't deform.

For my website its important that i can click the ON and AROUND the img, so `background-image:` and `100%` value issn't a option. On the Fiddle example You can see that the `img` is expanding to much on "Portrait Div"

Neither the `img` or the parent has a set height or width. (no javascript just pure css please).

```css
.img1 {
    height: auto;
    width:100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
    background-color: #966;
}
.img2 {
    height: 100%;
    width:auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
    background-color: #966;
}


.portrait {
    height: 60vh;
    width: 15vw;
    float:left;

}

.landscape {
    height: 15vw;
    width: 60vh;
    float:left;

}

div {
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px;
    background: #8591aa;
}
```

```html
Portrait Div
<div class="portrait">
    <img class="img1" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkF9Q.jpg">
</div>


<br style="clear: both;">
<br style="clear: both;">

Landscape Div
<div class="landscape">
    <img class="img2" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkF9Q.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: The question is unclear. If the snippet doesn't show the result you're trying to achieve, then what are you trying to achieve? But, if it does, you've already solved your problem, right?

Comment: If i could make a working snippet having hieght:auto;  width: auto; full parent size with img Aspect ratio, without stretching the img element(red background,as shown in fiddle) i would not have to post a question here ^^. The fiddle is as told in the description what happens with the knowledge gatherd from older Stackoverflow topics. normaly people do not mind that the img is invissible stretched (height or width at 100%) but i need to click around the img as stated in description. so i need the img Element as close as possible to  Aspect ratio. Please edit my description if its not readable,

Comment: i have altered the description to hopefully explain myself better, and created a Fiddle which shows how it should look like, i have also created a Fiddle that shows what happens when the parent size has changes(what i'm trying to avoid).