# Is there a way to resize images based on if they are vertical or horizontal using cycle2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cycle2

I want to resize the picture so the whole picture is always visible without scroll bars. Landscape pictures should go all the way to the edges, while vertical pictures should have a margin on the side, also, all pictures should be centered.

All the images have slightly different heights and widths. I am testing it with just 4 pictures, but I later plan to add a lot more.

This is what I have so far:

```
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.cycle2.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
  * {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }

  body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    display: block;
    max-height: 100%;
  }

  img {
    max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; margin: 0;
  }

  .cycle-slideshow {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;

  }
</style>

<body>
  <div class="cycle-slideshow">
    <img src="photos/NYC_Skyline_Revised.jpg" alt="NYC Skyline Photo">
    <img src="photos/MinionDrawing-1.jpg" alt="NYC Skyline Photo">
    <img src="photos/NYC_Skyline_Daytime.jpg" alt="NYC Skyline Photo">
    <img src="photos/HeavenlySunrise-2.jpg" alt="Sunrise Photo">
  </div>
  <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) check if width is greater than height

[How to get image size (height & width) using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript)

```
var img = document.getElementById('imageid'); 
//or however you get a handle to the IMG
var width = img.clientWidth;
var height = img.clientHeight;
```

2) Either

[How do I auto-resize an image to fit a div container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029422/how-do-i-auto-resize-an-image-to-fit-a-div-container)

```
max-width:100%;
max-height:100%;
```

or same as above to desired % width for non landscape

[You can use jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/css/) like `$(element).css( "width", "100%" );`  to go 100% width of container or browser w/e