# Set Background Image as per dynamic content?

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to set the background-image according to the dynamic content .

My `html` code like below

```
<div class="main-div">
     <div class="content-div">

     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: how are identifying the dynamic content?

Comment: if i am interpreting it right, when ever you set the dynamic content itself , may be using .html() function you can set the background also by using .css() function.

if not you can use .html() to get the content and the go ahead with the rest of the steps

Comment: who down-vote ? give me reason why ?

Comment: How do you get the dynamic content? Its relation with the background image? Does the dynamic content keep on changing? Do you have this dynamic images saved?.....

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var imageUrl = 'https://www.stoneycreekhunting.co.nz/2_Key_Features_Rainwear_Insulation.png';

  $("<div class='dynamic-element'/>", {
    text: ""
  }).appendTo(".content-div");

  $('.dynamic-element').css({
    'background-image': 'url('+imageUrl+')',
    'background-size': 'cover',
    'height': '100%'
  });
});
```

```css
.content-div {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:120px;height:120px;" class="main-div">
  <div class="content-div">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i can't fix teh height width of either main-div or content-div because content div may be auto-populate  the large Text content or images etc

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029422/how-do-i-auto-resize-an-image-to-fit-a-div-container