# How to resize image from URL and display fixed width on React Native?

Tags: image, react-native, resize

Somehow I could not figure this out. I have tried several solutions available online, but none of them worked.

Here is the issue. I have some wide images that I wanted to stack on top of each other. The height does not matter, but I want it to have a fixed width. For some reason, the images are being cropped.

I want it to look like this. For example, if you change `.meat`'s height to `10px`, it will resize but will maintain its ratio.

http://jsfiddle.net/iggyfiddle/mtL7e2jz/

This is the image code:

```
  {items.map((item, index) =>
    <View key={index}>
      <View style={styles.imageWrapper}>
        { item.image_url_large && <Image style={styles.image} resizeMode='cover' source={{ uri: item.image_url_large }} /> }
      </View>
    </View>
  )}
```

It is mapping over an array of several images.

I have tried:

a simple

const styles = {
  image: {
    height: 100
  },
};

I tried following the same pattern on the fiddle, by giving it fixed height and width according to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029422/how-do-i-auto-resize-an-image-to-fit-a-div-container)

```
const styles = {
  imageWrapper: {
    height: 50,
    width: 400
  },
  image: {
    height: '100%'
  },
};
```

But it still crops the top bun and tomato

[image: attempt2]

I have tried some solutions described on this [GH discussion](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/950) but they don't seem to work.

How can I automatically resize the image from web to fixed width without it being cropped?

Answer (score 1):

use resizeMode='contain' instead of cover and specify the width and height.

```
<Image
   style={{width:300,height:300}}
   source={{ uri: display_image_small }}
   resizeMode='contain'>
</Image>
```