# Fix image height to 150px css

Tags: html, css

How can I auto fit an image in a div. I have a div inside which there is an image. If the image is big then it takes up half of the screen. I want it so that the image is shrunk and fits in a div of 150px or so. So as along as the image has a height of 150px, then the image will fit in the box. if it is bigger then it should shrink.

I tried:

```
.crop {
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}
```

But doesnt work. I also tried `max-width: 1fr` `

Comment: .crop is a class of div or image??. add html code too

Comment: Please go read [ask], and how to create a [mcve]. _“I also tried `max-width: 1fr`”_ - `fr` is for working with CSS grids, you can not use it in other contexts. Also, why max-width, when you were talking about the image _height_ so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply the size limitation to the image itself. See below. Hope that helps.

```css
.crop img {
  max-height: 150px;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="crop">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x350">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.crop {
    height: 150px;
    max-height:150px
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
  }
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit about the result of this code? In that case does he even need the `height` property at all?

Comment: max height should work for you, if it is not working please provide snippet of your code, so that we can help more.

Comment: I'n not the OP. I'm just asking about the combination of `height` and `max-height` having the same value...

Comment: @Tee F, this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029422/how-do-i-auto-resize-an-image-to-fit-a-div-container

Answer (score 1):

You can use object-fit:contain like:-

```
 .crop img{
    object-fit:contain;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to apply `height:100%` to the image

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.crop {
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

.crop img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="crop">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/600x300" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Where is crop img being called?

Comment: @TeeF apply `height:100%` to the image and `max-width:100%`..it will automatically fit into the 150px height div

Answer (score 1):

```css
.crop {
    height: 150px;
        width: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
  }
        .crop img{
            width: 100%;
        }
```

```html
 <div class="crop">
        <img src="https://m.guardtime.com/photos/tech_image.jpg">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> So as along as the image has a height of 150px, then the image will
>   fit in the box.

**You can try using object-fit**

Sample below using `object-fit:cover` will fill the image in the `.crop` container. It will maintain its aspect ratio but but often cropping the image .

```css
.crop{
  height:150px;
  width:150px;
}

img {
  height: inherit;
  width:inherit;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="crop">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x550" alt="">
</div>
```

Alternative if you want just the image to follow only the height of the container and maintain it's aspect-ratio. you can use `object-fit:contain`. Just don't set the width of the container.

```css
.crop{
  height:150px;
}

img {
  height: inherit;
  width:inherit;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="crop">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x550" alt="">
</div>
```