# Image resize or cropped based on the Parent div size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have div which have 600px width and 631px height initially .

There is two input field where user can change width and height .
Inside this div i have an image

so the structure

```
<div class="container-div">
 <img src="img.jpg" class="new-img">
</div>
```

so when user resize the div size , image also **need to be resize proportionally**. It will not be stretched .

How i can do this ?

**Note :** i wrote the code for to resize the div after user entering their width and height . so i actually try to get code after div resize .

```
$(".input1, .input2").on("change",function(){
   measurement_change();
});


function measurement_change(){
 after calculation i set new_width and new_height 
 $(".container-div").css("width", new_width);
 $(".container-div").css("height", new_height);

   After this i hav e to resize image propotionally 

}
```

Please check.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029422/how-do-i-auto-resize-an-image-to-fit-a-div-container

Comment: What about if user leave empty one of the inputs?

Comment: it will take the default image width and height

Comment: For example if user enter 100px for height, you want to set width 600px (default) ? so by this, impossible to make an unstretched image.

Comment: then we can crop the image right?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".input1, .input2").on("change",function(){
   var width = $('.input1').val();
   var height = $('.input2').val();
   $(".container-div").css("width", width);
   $(".container-div").css("height", height);
   $(".new-img").css("max-width",width);
});
```

Comment: $(".new-img").css("max-width",width); is good idea . But i am not sure that this will give the desired result.