# Image shrinks when resizing browser's height but not when resizing the width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make it so that the height is restricted to the height of the device the image is viewed on so that you can view the entire image without having to scroll down.

To accomplish this I've used:

```
.specific-image {
  display: block;
  max-height: 92vh;
  max-width: 1240px;
}
```

So if the image is 500x1000 px, it'll take 92vh height and if it's 1000x500, it'll have width of 1240px and height (most probably) less than 92vh.

The problem with that is that if I resize the height of the browser the image scales down, however, if I scale the width, my browser will cut part of the image and I'll have to scroll horizontally to see the full image.

Not sure how to get the best of both worlds.

https://codepen.io/BozhidarSK/pen/NBKyyW

```css
.specific-image-flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.specific-image-column {
  flex: 4;
}

.specific-image-container-element {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.specific-image {
  display: block;
  max-height: 92vh;
  max-width: 1240px;
}

.stickySpecificContainer {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="specific-image-flex-container">

  <div class="specific-image-column">
    <div class='specific-image-container-element'>
      <div class="stickySpecificContainer">
        <img class='specific-image' src='https://i.redd.it/1v3x2pxkjy611.png' alt='Random image' />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: add `width:40%;` or similar to specific-image class.

Comment: But that just makes the image have width of 40% of parent element? That doesn't solve anything.

Comment: Are you saying you want the image to be no taller than the browser height AND no wider than the browser width?

Comment: @Bobimaru see revised answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the image to be maximum 100% wide by default and 1240px if the screen is wider than 1240px. You can achieve the desired result using media queries:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.specific-image {
  display: block;
  max-height: 92vh;
  max-width: 100%;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1240px) {
  .specific-image {
    max-width: 1240px;
  }
}
```

```html
<img class="specific-image" src="https://dummyimage.com/1600x600/000/fff" alt="dummy image">
```

Same demo with square image:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.specific-image {
  display: block;
  max-height: 92vh;
  max-width: 100%;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1240px) {
  .specific-image {
    max-width: 1240px;
  }
}
```

```html
<img class="specific-image" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x600/000/fff" alt="dummy image">
```

Answer (score 0):

give max-width:100% to the image instead of the pixel value, the percentage value will make sure that max width of the image 100% of the document.

```
.specific-image {
  display: block;
  max-height: 92vh;
  max-width: 100%
  }
```

```css
.specific-image-flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.specific-image-column {
  flex: 4;
}

.specific-image-container-element {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.specific-image {
  display: block;
  max-height: 92vh;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.stickySpecificContainer {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="specific-image-flex-container">

  <div class="specific-image-column">
    <div class='specific-image-container-element'>
      <div class="stickySpecificContainer">
        <img class='specific-image' src='https://i.redd.it/1v3x2pxkjy611.png' alt='Random image' />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This fixed the problem I had with the scaling, however, this way my image can have a width of over 1240px? Is there any way to keep the responsiveness by using % and still restrict max-width to 1240px?

Comment: hi Bobimaru, the image width won't go over the original width unless you specify it that way, so using 100% is the best way to make sure that the image will stay responsive.

Comment: You could try width: 100%; max-width: 1240px;

Comment: Hmmm, after adding width: 100%; max-width: 1240px, the image stretches unproportionally if I resize the height of the browser.

Comment: @wiiiiilllllll, that is not going to work, width 100% will stretch the image

Comment: Is it even possible to accomplish what I'm asking? Should I just pick one of the other variations.

Comment: hi Bobimaru, what other solutions are you looking for, this answer did not work for you ?

Comment: if you are not sure about this, take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029422/how-do-i-auto-resize-an-image-to-fit-a-div-container

Comment: It works if I wanted to have max-width of 100%, however, I need to have max-width of 1240px while still keeping responsiveness. Obviously your answer is second best to what I want and if I don't find a solution to my problem, I'd use it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174666/discussion-between-jismon-thomas-and-bobimaru).

Comment: Sorry for the delay, unexpected chore came up. Are you still up for a chat?

Answer (score 0):

`92vh` is 92% of the view height. `vw` is used for view width.

```
.specific-image {
  display: block;
  max-height: 92vh;
  max-width: 92vw;
}
```