# Why does my image not contain to the wrapper div?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to wrap my image inside a container div although when doing so my image still takes up the full width and height of the original size. Instead, I  want the image to take up the according width and height of the wrapper container instead of using its own.

I have tried to use object-fit:cover; although it does not seem to be working in my situation.

```css
.desktop-slideshow {
  height: 500px;
  width: auto;
  outline: 4px solid red;
}

.desktop-slideshow img {
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="desktop-slideshow">
  <img src="https://www.placehold.it/1920x1080" alt="">
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5khs1c2p/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I auto-resize an image to fit a div container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029422/how-do-i-auto-resize-an-image-to-fit-a-div-container)

Comment: How about `max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%;`?

Comment: `object-fit` only works if you set a height and width on your image. Just add `height: 100%; width: 100%` to your `img`. CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `object-fit` if you have set any width or height for the image.

```
.desktop-slideshow img{
  object-fit: cover;
  max-width:100%;
  min-height:100%;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

[Forked fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gu8asyj4/) or Snippet:

```css
.desktop-slideshow {
  height: 500px;
  width: auto;
  outline: 4px solid red;
}

.desktop-slideshow img {
 object-fit: cover;
 max-width:100%;
 max-height:100%;
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="desktop-slideshow">
  <img src="https://www.placehold.it/1920x1080" alt="">
</div>
```

See the following [link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp) for more detail if you want to use [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)

Answer (score -1):

would this work for you?

```
.desktop-slideshow{
  height:500px;
  width:auto;
  outline: 4px solid red;
}

.desktop-slideshow img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I'd imagine OP was using `object-fit` in an attempt to maintain aspect ratio, something that `width: 100%; height: 100%` will not achieve on its own. To be clear though, I actually haven't downvoted your answer, as OP really hasn't specified that "maintaining aspect ratio" is or is not important.